# What is the difference between short (&,|) and long (&&, ||) forms of AND, OR logical operators in R?

Tags: r, logical-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: subset() logical-and operator for chaining conditions should be & not &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933598/r-subset-logical-and-operator-for-chaining-conditions-should-be-not)

What is the difference between short (`&`,`|`) and long (`&&`, `||`) forms of AND, OR logical operators in R?

For example:

1. `x==0 & y==1`
2. `x==0 && y==1`
3. `x==0 | y==1`
4. `x==0 || y==1`

I always use the short forms in my code. Does it have any handicaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` and `|` - are element-wise and can be used with vector operations, whereas, `||` and `&&` always generate single `TRUE` or `FALSE`

theck the difference:

```
> x <- 1:5
> y <- 5:1
> (x > 2) & (y < 3) 
  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> (x > 2) && (y < 3) # here operaand && takes only 1'st elements from logical
                     # vectors (x>2) and (y<3)
> FALSE
```

So, `&&` and `||` are commonly used in `if (condition) state_1 else state_2` statements, as
dealing with vectors of length `1`

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to add that ´||´and ´&&´ are prefered in if clauses when only the first value is used.

Comment: @lselzer ... because `||` and `&&` *short-circuit*, i.e. they don't check subsequent clauses unnecessarily.  i.e. `A || B || C` stops evaluating and returns `TRUE` as soon as it finds a `TRUE` element, while `A && B && C` stops evaluating and returns `FALSE` as soon as it finds a `FALSE` element ... this is useful in constructs such as `if (!is.na(x) && x>0)` ...

Comment: @Max, a subtle point, but `&&` doesn't always return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Consider `TRUE && NA`, which returns `NA`.