# Running T.Test in R comparing two different columns

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I have to run a t.test in R on the following:
**If the YearsAtCompany of Single is less than Married**

Meaning somehow I need to compare the YearsatCompany with Marital Status

I have tried:

```
t.test(EmployeeAttrition$YearsAtCompany[Single],EmployeeAttrition$YearsAtCompany[Married],alternative = "less")
```

But that isn't giving me the information correctly. I am fairly new at R. And have researched other questions on here and still can't get the code right.

Sample data:

[image: Data Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R multiple conditions in row selection of matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762402/r-multiple-conditions-in-row-selection-of-matrix)

Comment: Do **not** post data as images or graphic files, please edit your question and post the output of `dput(EmployeeAttrition)`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `with` and properly subset your data (You needed to specific the variable in EmployeeAttrition to subset by).

```
with(EmployeeAttrition, t.test(YearsAtCompany[MaritalStatus == "Single"], YearsAtCompany[MaritalStatus == "Married"], alternative = "less")
```

Comment: If it helped, please feel free to accept it as an answer.