# Subsetting my data frame by Date

Tags: r, subset

I have seen the code somewhere, but haven't found it in the 30 mins I've been searching.

Here's the code I have for now

```
library('quantmod')
today <- Sys.Date()
getSymbols("SBUX")
retSBUX <- dailyReturn(SBUX)
starbucks <- data.frame(SBUX)
starbucks[,7] <- as.Date(row.names(starbucks))
row.names(starbucks) <- NULL
starbucks <- subset(starbucks, starbucks[,7] >= "2015-04-06" && starbucks[,7] <= today)
```

When I run this code, I get a data frame with 0 variable and just the column names in the data frame.

Comment: `&&` operator examines only the first element. Use `&`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933598/r-gotcha-logical-and-operator-for-combining-conditions-is-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should used the vectorized logical operator `&` instead of the short-circuit operator (`&&`):

```
starbucks <- subset(starbucks, starbucks[,7] >= "2015-04-06" & starbucks[,7] <= today)
```

See [R - boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and).

Comment: I find it intriguing that you can compare a `Date` object to a string and it works just fine. Never would have thought that would work.

Comment: @thelatemail what about `1 < "2"` ?

Comment: @bergant - I know that works, but it just seems risky, as in `1 < "02"` , which would be much safer with `1 < as.numeric("02")`. I notice the `Date-to-string` comparison fails if the date is not in an unambiguous, standard format, so I guess that's okay. Though it is still a risky practice, in that doing `Sys.time() < "1900-01-01 00:00"` returns `TRUE`, so the pattern doesn't hold when dealing with all date/datetime objects.

Comment: so essentially, I could remove the `& starbucks[,7] <= today` part and it would've worked.