# R if statement for characters exist in range

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to create a new column if character strings exist for both columns A & B of a dataframe. I thought the following would work, but its not finding characters in every cell:

```
df = structure(list(Participant = 1:3, A = c("char", "foo", ""), B = c("char2","", "")), .Names = c("Participant", "A", "B"), row.names = c(NA,-3L), class = "data.frame")

df$newcolumn <- ifelse(nchar(data$A)>0 && nchar(data$B)>0, "character", "nocharacter")
```

I'm unexpectedly getting 'nocharacter' for all rows. Anyone have suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: replace `&&` by `&`

Comment: to add to what HubertL said, && is only comparing the first element of each vector, see `?base::Logic`

Comment: This might be a better dupe: [R gotcha: logical-and operator for combining conditions is & not &&](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6933598/903061)

Comment: @Gregor Replacing '&&' with '&' does not solve the problem. I get a logical(0) as a response.

Comment: The other problem in your question code is that you use both `df` and `data` as the name of your data frame. If you change `data$` to `df$` it works fine for me.