# IF condition for each record using R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to categorize FICO scores in three categories and want to create a new column where the corresponding value can be displayed.

My data:

```
FICO
650
450
700
```

Expected output

```
FICO    Category
650     Moderate
450     Poor
700     Excellent
```

I wrote an if statement for this

```
model_data$ficocategory <- if (model_data$FICO>=350 && 
model_data$FICO<=500) {
print("POOR")
  } else if (model_data$FICO>=501 && model_data$FICO<=650) {
print("MODERATE")
  } else
    print("EXCELLENT")
```

But the output I get is

```
[1] "MODERATE"
```

Comment: `&&` isn't vectorized. Use `&`.

Comment: @JohnColeman if i use only '&' it gives output as [1] "EXCELLENT"

Comment: If you want to create a vector -- you should also use the `ifelse()` *function* rather than the `if ... else` construct. Also -- printing in the middle of an assignment statement seems a bit odd.

Comment: Tried doing that too. ifelse(model_data$FICO>=350 & model_data$FICO<=500 , "POOR", 
       ifelse(model_data$FICO>=501 & model_data$FICO<=650 , "MODERATE"), "EXCELLENT") Gives an error: Error in ifelse(model_data$FICO >= 350 & model_data$FICO <= 500, "POOR",  : 
  unused argument ("EXCELLENT")

Comment: Try `model_data$ficocategory <- ifelse(model_data$FICO>=350 & model_data$FICO<=500,"POOR",ifelse(model_data$FICO>=501 & model_data$FICO<=650,"MODERATE","EXCELLENT"))`

Comment: Well this works. I get my mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1 - The `&&` only compares the first element of vectors.  So, for instance, `model_data$FICO >= 501 && model_data$FICO <= 650` is just comparing the first element of each logical vector returned by both sides of the comparison, which for your data is `TRUE` and `TRUE` (650 is >= 501 and 650 <= 650).  Using `&` will solve this problem so that a logical vector is returned for each element-wise comparison. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027840/whats-the-differences-between-and-and-in-r) post for more information.

2 - Has already been addressed in the comments.  You want to be using the vectorized `ifelse` function that will perform the logical comparisons and return a vector of values.  In your comment above just move `"EXCELLENT"` inside the prior `ifelse` statement: `... , "MODERATE", "EXCELLENT"))`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed insight.