# `all observations are in the same group` when `bartlett.test`

Tags: r

```
variance_homo<-function(df,col1,col2){
    if (is.numeric(df[,col2]) & nlevels(df[,col1])>2){
    bartlett_res<-bartlett.test(col2~col1,df,na.action=na.omit)
    leven_res<-leveneTest(col2,col1,data=df,na.action=na.omit)
    }
    return(bartlett_res)
}
```

Above script is a simple function,when I run it ,got error as below:

```
> variance_homo(iris,'Species','Sepal.Length')
Error in bartlett.test.default("Sepal.Length", "Species") : 
  all observations are in the same group
Called from: bartlett.test.default("Sepal.Length", "Species")
```

Wha's the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a revised version that returns the results of both test run.

```
variance_homo <- function(df, col1, col2){
  if (is.numeric(df[[col2]]) && nlevels(df[[col1]]) >= 2){
    fmla <- paste(col2, col1, sep = '~')
    fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
    bartlett_res <- bartlett.test(fmla, df, na.action = na.omit)
    leven_res <- car::leveneTest(fmla, data = df, na.action = na.omit)
    list(bartlett = bartlett_res, levene = leven_res)
  }else stop('not enough levels.')
}

variance_homo(iris, 'Species', 'Sepal.Length')
```

Comment: I noticed you use `&&` instead of `&`,and use `df[[col2]]` instead of `df[,col2]`.Why?

Comment: @kittygirl Because `&` is the vectorized form and that conjunction has only one element on each side. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and). And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027840/whats-the-differences-between-and-and-in-r).

Answer (score 1):

Try the double bracket approach:

```
variance_homo<-function(df,col1,col2){
    if (is.numeric(df[[col2]]) & nlevels(df[[col1]])>2){
    bartlett_res <- bartlett.test(df[[col2]]~df[[col1]],df,na.action=na.omit)
    leven_res <- leveneTest(df[[col2]],df[[col1]],data=df,na.action=na.omit)
}
return(bartlett_res)
}
```

Then:

```
variance_homo(iris,'Species','Sepal.Length')

    Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances

data:  df[[col2]] by df[[col1]]
Bartlett's K-squared = 16.006, df = 2, p-value = 0.0003345
```

Comment: What's the difference between `df[,col2]` and `df[[col2]]` ? As I know, they are same thing.