# ERROR in R.... missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement

The following is part of my R script:

```
for (i in 1:N-1) {
  if (-50<nw.bank[i] && 50>nw.bank[i]) {
      rl[i+1] <- (rl[i]+0.001)
  } 
    else {
      rl[i+1] <- rl[i]
  }
}
```

When run, I get the following message:

```
"Error in if (-50 < nw.bank[i] && 50 > nw.bank[i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

Can anyone help me out? Thank you so much!

best,
hyun

Comment: I don't know R but try with enclosing each expression in paranthesis :`((-50 < nw.bank[i]) && (50 > nw.bank[i]))` , Probably !

Comment: You'll get an error if `nw.bank[i]` is `NA`.

Comment: Hi LostBrit, yeah, you are right. If I run the if statement with Ctrl+R, i.e. (-50<nw.bank[i] && 50>nw.bank[i]), I get the result as: [1] NA. This is strange because nw.bank is well defined and separately running nw.bank gives a correct result. Do you know what is wrong? I really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Note that `1:N-1` is parsed as `(1:N) - 1`. This means your loop is iterating over 0, 1, 2, ... (N - 1), and the test using `nw.bank[i]` will error out on the first iteration. You probably meant `1:(N - 1)`.

Comment: Hi Hong, I really appreciate for your comment. It helped. But there seems to be a problem elsewhere as well. If I run the if statement with Ctrl+R, i.e. (-50<nw.bank[i] && 50>nw.bank[i]), I get the result as: [1] NA. This is strange because nw.bank is well defined and separately running nw.bank gives a correct result. Do you know what is wrong? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

R for loops run slower when compared to code that handles vectors directly.

This procedure you give can be vectorized as follows:

Get some random values for nw.bank so the calculation can be demonstrated:

```
nw.bank<- 200*runif(20)-100 

[1]  43.273799  19.051499  37.552510  76.940632 -59.176684 -27.379326
[7] -37.512520  77.776610  88.127792 -91.213580 -50.691943  78.697820
[13]  36.933503 -76.973450  28.143336 -55.136574 -70.693362 -14.213375
[19]  15.666707  -3.072321
```

Note there is only one ampersand (&) in a vectorized AND

```
as.numeric(((-50<nw.bank) & (50>nw.bank)))
   [1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

Now multiply by 0.001 and take cumulative sum

```
   cumsum(0.001*as.numeric(((-50<nw.bank) & (50>nw.bank))))

[1] 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.004 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005
[13] 0.006 0.006 0.007 0.007 0.007 0.008 0.009 0.010
```

Now you need an adjustable initial value, perhaps, and you are done

```
rlinit <- 3.0; 
rl <- cumsum(0.001*as.numeric(((-50<nw.bank) & (50>nw.bank)))) + rlinit



[1] 3.001 3.002 3.003 3.003 3.003 3.004 3.005 3.005 3.005 3.005 3.005 3.005
[13] 3.006 3.006 3.007 3.007 3.007 3.008 3.009 3.010
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you so much! But is this the only solution? If I can find and fix any logical error with my scripts I would like to go with a simpler approach since I have some more parts in my script that are similiar to the one I posted. best, hyun

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it.  Use what works for you. I would argue that 2 lines are simpler than 8, it is easy to read and R will run it faster, but it also takes longer for a programmer to write and requires knowing a lot of R functions.

Comment: Got it! I'll try that out. I really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the problem with `1:N-1` as Hong suggested, then try to find if there is `NA` in `nw.bank` using `any(is.na(nw.bank))`, and use `&` instead of `&&` unless you have a good reason (see [R - boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and)).

Comment: Hi Cogitovita, I tried is.na and yes there are many NAs. But, the number of NA are different between the result from is.na and running nw.bank separately. Anyway, I cannot figure out why I am getting NAs. Could you help me out please? I really appreciate :)

Comment: For counting the number of `NA`s, I recommend to use `sum(is.na(nw.bank))`. The `NA`s may be introduced by unstream analysis.

Comment: I see.. Could you please tell me what you mean by 'unstream analysis'? I really appreciate!

Comment: How do you get `nw.bank`? Do you expect that it may contain `NA`? If not, you should inspect the code that generates `nw.bank` and see what happenes there.