# R if else statement issue

Tags: r, if-statement

When I run this very simple code

```
c <- seq(0, 1, length.out=4)
x <- 0.5
for (l in 1:length(c)) {
    if (l>1 & x>c[l-1] & x<c[l]) {
        print(x)
    }
}
```

I have the following error in the console

```
Error in if ((l > 1 & x > c[l - 1] & x < c[l])) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

The most interesting part is that if try to create a logical variable with the "if" condition, everything works fine:

```
> (l>1 & x>c[l-1] & x<c [l])
logical(0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not start from `l in 2:length(c)` and compare, `c[l-1] is c[0] ` in your first case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That was a stupid mistake. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and) replacing `&` with `&&` would solve the issue for my case.

Comment: Note that is resolving the `length zero` error because it is short circuiting.  This might be exactly what you are looking for, but you should double check your `if`-clauses to be certain