# How do if-statements work on sequences?

Tags: r, if-statement, sequence

```
x = seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.1)
```

Why does

```
x > 0
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

take every value of the sequence while

```
x > 0 && x < 5
[1] FALSE
```

takes only the first value?

Comment: Those are different operators. Type `help("&&")` for more info on the difference

Comment: Thanks! ? && doesnt seem to work in my RStudio, is there a way to look this up online?

Comment: See my edited comment. The important part of the help file is: "& and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses."

Comment: You need to quote `?"&&"`

Comment: See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6559049/210673