# why do we have two types of logical an in R

Tags: r

I have been reading up about the difference between & and && in R.

I understand that, unlike in other languages where & is for bitwise operations and && is used for conditions like **height > 150 && height < 180**, in R, both are for the latter. For bitwise, there are other functions such as **bitwAnd(a, b)**

However, what's the difference between & and &&. From what I've read, all I have understood is that "**The longer form**(&& I guess) **is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses**"

However, I was trying out something where one seems to work and the other doesn't?

```
> which( (df$Cost > 14789) & (df$Cost < 14791) )
[1]  29989  69576 116578 137242 160072
> which( (df$Cost > 14789) && (df$Cost < 14791) )
integer(0)
```

Comment: The `&` operator is vectorized, the `&&` operator is not

Comment: The "&&" function only processes the first element of each of its arguments. It's really designed for program flow control and not much else.

Answer (score 0):

`&` performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators.

`&&` evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined.

So in your code

```
> which( (df$Cost > 14789) & (df$Cost < 14791) )
[1]  29989  69576 116578 137242 160072
> which( (df$Cost > 14789) && (df$Cost < 14791) )
integer(0)
```

The first statement evaluates the vector elementwise, hence the results.
The second only the first element of the vector.

Comment: I'm sorry jebsel, I don't think I got you there. We use an AND statement, so that all the sub-conditions are evaluated. How does only processing the first sub-condition help? And even if only the first sub-condition was evaluated, it should still evaluate (df$Cost > 14789) and return some results.
I don't think I was able to follow you. Please clarify.

Comment: && evaluated the first element of the vector df$Cost   ... for more info read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and as marked as duplicate question above