# Sub selecting a data frame on a range in R

Tags: r, subset

If I create a simple data frame using:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- x*2
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

and then I try sub selecting where x>30 and x<40 by doing the following

```
df[df$x>30 && df$x<40]
```

I get:

```
data frame with 0 columns and 100 rows
```

I'd like the understand why I get that and how to fix it.

Comment: Just for future searches: I think that the proper term for what you are doing is "subsetting". Using the right term will allow you to find better solution to your problems (in any case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have two errors, try this instead:

```
 df[df$x>30 & df$x<40,]
#     x  y
# 31 31 62
# 32 32 64
# 33 33 66
# 34 34 68
# 35 35 70
# 36 36 72
# 37 37 74
# 38 38 76
# 39 39 78
```

**Explanation**:

The first error is that you are using `&&` instead of `&`. You want the first form if you are sure there is a comparison of vectors of length one. [See this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and).

The second one, is that you are missing a comma (","). Writing the condition for subsetting first, then a comma, then nothing, will select the `rows` that satisfy this condition.

You can check the differences on subsets with that same `df` when you try `df[]`, `df[1,]` and `df[,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

just to add some variety of solutions, there other ways to do so. Another way is with the `subset` function and/or with `%in%` (note the different behaviour):

```
subset(df, x > 30 & x < 40)
subset(df, x %in% c(31:39))
df[df$x %in% c(31:39), ]
```

or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
# Standart dplyr notation
df %>% filter(x > 30, x < 40)
# Non-Standart dplyr notation
df %>% filter(x > 30 & x < 40)
```

all have the same result:

```
    x  y
31 31 62
32 32 64
33 33 66
34 34 68
35 35 70
36 36 72
37 37 74
38 38 76
39 39 78
```

Comment: with dplyr you can pass the filter conditions as multiple arguments, avoiding the `&` operator that was tripping up the OP: `df %>% filter(x > 30, x < 40)`

Comment: @SamFirke yes I forget that!, thank you for the feedback, I update my post.