# R: How to check if more than one strings exist in a string?

Tags: r

```
a <- "quick brown fox"
b <- "quick brown dog"
```

I want to know if both the "quick" AND "fox" strings exist in a,b.

i.e.,
applying the answer to this question on,

a - should return TRUE

b - should return FALSE

Comment: To use one pattern, try `grepl("quick.*fox|fox.*quick", x)`

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: @Heroka the original problem was like where a bunch of a,b,.. values being the colnames of a `data.frame` which is an extension to this question. I tried `grepl("brown", colnames(data.frame)) && grepl("fox", colnames(data.frame)` which is fundamentally wrong and would just compare the output lists of the above two logical vectors.
I still couldn't figure out how to apply this to a colnames(data.frame) object though.

Comment: @akilat90 You should remove the `&&` and use a single `&`

Comment: @akrun - just read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and) Thanks.
Btw @PierreLafortune your approach worked for me to apply this to a whole vector. I used `c <- c(a,b)` and then `grepl("quick.*fox", c)` and it returned `TRUE FALSE` . Your method of using `grepl("quick.*fox|fox.*quick", x)` yields the same result. I think I'm missing something about the wildcard search. Can you shed some light on this? Thanks

Comment: @akilat90  The `quick.*fox|fox.*quick` is to match all strings where `quick` comes before `fox` or `fox` comes before `quick`.  If you have only instances where the `quick` comes before `fox`, the single `quick.*fox` should work.  Again, as I mentioned in my solution, using `\\b` to separate the word boundary makes it specific to avoid any surprises.

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun I'm a bit slow as I'm kind of new to this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a double `grepl` with `&` (more safer)

```
grepl('quick', a) & grepl('fox', a)
#[1] TRUE

grepl('quick', a) & grepl('fox', b)
#[1] FALSE
```

Or if we know the position of 'fox' beforehand, i.e. if it follows after `quick` (as in the example), then we can use a regex 'quick' followed by 0 or more characters followed by 'fox'.  We may also flank it with word boundary (`\\b`) to avoid surprises i.e. to avoid matching words like `quickness` or `foxy`.

```
grepl('.*\\bquick\\b.*\\bfox\\b', a)
#[1] TRUE
grepl('.*\\bquick\\b.*\\bfox\\b', b)
#[1] FALSE
```

As I mentioned earlier, this will give `FALSE` for `foxy`

```
grepl('.*\\bquick\\b.*\\bfox\\b', 'quick brown foxy')
#[1] FALSE
```

If the position varies,

```
grepl('.*\\bquick\\b.*\\bfox\\b|.*\\bfox\\b.*\\bquick\\b', b)
#[1] FALSE

grepl('.*\\bquick\\b.*\\bfox\\b|.*\\bfox\\b.*\\bquick\\b', a)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi @akrun,

Your solution answers my question. I'm accepting.