# Error: object 'len' not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, loops, programming-tools

I like to give little more information. I started with 4 genes and defined their on and off conditions, using the below script:

```
Proli <- function (DISC1, GSK3B, DIXDC1, CTNNB1){     
  inputs <- permutations(2,4,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE);
  if (DISC1 == 1 && GSK3B == 0 && DIXDC1 == 1 && CTNNB1 == 1){
    Proliferation <- "TRUE"  
  }
  else
  {
    Proliferation <- "FALSE"
  }
  Proliferation
}
```

then I loaded `gtools` and `heirpart`.

```
inputs <- permutations(2,26,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE)
len <- length[inputs]
for(i in 1:len) 
{
  if(inputs[i,1] == 1 && inputs[i,2] == 0 && inputs[i,3] == 1 && inputs[i,4] == 1){
    #Constructing  a Truth Table
    output[i] <- 1
  }
  else{
    output[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Now I get Error in output[i] <- 0 : object 'output' not found

Comment: You have to define `len` before the `for` loop. From where comes your script?

Comment: maybe you mean `for(i in 1:nrow(inputs))` ?

Comment: Where have you initialized object 'len' in your script?

Comment: Also, be careful with your use of booleans. [R - boolean operators && and ||](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and).

Comment: @Pascal "How to spot a C/java programmer learning R" :-)

Answer (score -1):

***#just add on top of your script***

```
len <- lenght(object on with you do your loop)
```

or

```
len <- nrow(object on with you do your loop)



for(i in 1:len) {
        if(inputs[i,1] == 1 && inputs[i,2] == 0 && inputs[i,3] == 1 && inputs[i,4] == 1){
            #Constructing  a Truth Table
            output[i] <- 1
        }
        else{
            output[i] <- 0
        }
    }
```