# set column value based on if statement using two other columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have data that belongs in a data frame, I want to change N/A values in "col1" where "col2" has text. Any "col1" N/A values which have text in "col2" I would like to change the "col1" value to "<1 Year":

Data:

```
col1    | col2
<1 YEAR | abcdefg
1 YEAR  | xyz
N/A     | abcde
N/A     | abc
N/A     |
```

This is the code I have tried for the first part:

```
df = mutate(df, col1 = ifelse(is.na(col1) && nchar(col2)>1,"lol",col1))
```

Comment: The `is.na` will not work if you have a character "N/A".  Read the dataset with `na.strings = "N/A"` in `read.table/read.csv`..  Also, you need only `&` for this to work (assuming that the NA is real)

Comment: More directly `&&` is used for scalar logic whereas `&` is used for vectors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and