# Translate dplyr filter to base R when there are NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a working `filter` statement in dplyr that I can't translate to base R

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(
    v1 = c("USA", "Canada", "Mexico"),
    v2 = c(NA, 1:5)
  )

x %>% filter(v1=="Canada",v2 %in% 3:5)

x[x$v1=="Canada" && x$v2 %in% 3:5,]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `& ! is.na(x$v2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(
   v1 = c("USA", "Canada", "Mexico"),
   v2 = c(NA, 1:5)
)

# filter 
x %>% filter(v1=="Canada",v2 %in% 3:5)
      v1 v2
1 Canada  4

# your approach
x[x$v1=="Canada" && x$v2 %in% 3:5,]
 v1 v2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

# second & removed
x[x$v1=="Canada" & x$v2 %in% 3:5,]
      v1 v2
5 Canada  4
```

Apart from the rowname, it gives the same result.

Look at this example to understand what was happening before (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and))

```
-2:2 >= 0
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
-2:2 >= 0 & -2:2 <= 0
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
-2:2 >= 0 && -2:2 <= 0
[1] FALSE
```

In some situations, you may encounter issues with `NA`s. Then it is advisable to wrap logical statements into `which`. `filter` filters out `NA`s by default. E.g.

```
# will include NA:
x[x$v2 > 3,]
       v1 v2
NA   <NA> NA
5  Canada  4
6  Mexico  5

# will exclude NA 
x[which(x$v2 > 3),]
      v1 v2
5 Canada  4
6 Mexico  5
```

Comment: Man, I thought `&&` was a short-circuted "and" meaning essentially `x && y` means if x is false don't even bother evaluating y. Similar `x || y` means if x is true don't even both evaluating y, but I was very wrong apparently. Thanks

Comment: Well, it is! But you don't want that here. You want a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` statements, one for each observation. If you only supply one single `FALSE` statement when `R` expects a vector, `R` will recycle it. Therefore, for each and every row you say `FALSE`, and thus you get the above outcome (no rows).

Answer (score 1):

`subset` is in base R, and functions similarly to `filter` in `dplyr`.  Is subset sufficient for you, or do you need the bracket notations for some reason?

```
> x <- data.frame(
+     v1 = c("USA", "Canada", "Mexico"),
+     v2 = c(NA, 1:5)
+ )
```

Via `dplyr`:

```
> x %>% filter(v1=="Canada",v2 %in% 3:5)
      v1 v2
1 Canada  4
```

Via base R/`subset`:

```
> subset(x, v1 == 'Canada' & v2 %in% 3:5)
      v1 v2
5 Canada  4
```