# R multiple conditions in if statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have read many of the if statement posts but have not been able to find an answer to my simple problem. 
I would like to create a new column in the data frame 'tester' based on a multiple condition if statement.

```
tester<- as.data.frame(matrix(data=c(seq(1,300,by=1.5)), ncol=4))

if (tester$V3> 200 && tester$V4>250){tester[,5] <- "one"} else tester$V5 <-NA
```

This gives me NAs for the entire column even though the last 17 rows are TRUE for both cases and should be "one". What is happening here? Thank you for your help!

Comment: tester$V5 <- ifelse (tester$V3> 200 & tester$V4>250,"one",NA)

Comment: thank you that works! why did mine not work?

Comment: Because you used &&

Comment: Rewrite like this to make it work `if (i <- (tester$V3> 200 & tester$V4>250)) {tester$V5[i] <- "one"} else {tester$V5[i] <-NA}`

Comment: @Vlo No this doesn't work (Try it with `tester <- data.frame(V3=c(1,220,3), V4=c(5,600,7))`) because the first value of the condition is used for the test and is `false`. This would work `if (i <- (tester$V3> 200 & tester$V4>250)) {tester$V5[i] <- "one"} else {tester$V5[i] <-"one"}` but is so ugly!!!

Comment: @HubertL Forgot to wrap `any` around the condition. Your code is the exact the same thing with a hypo instead. `if (any(i <- (tester$V3> 200 & tester$V4>250))) {tester$V5[i] <- "one"} else {tester$V5[i] <-NA}`

Comment: @Vlo there is no real reason to use a if then, it's clearer to write the statement in 2 lines : `i <- tester$V3> 200 & tester$V4>250` and `tester$V5[i] <- "one"`

Answer (score 15):

Read this thread [R - boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Basically, the `&` is vectorized, i.e. it acts on each element of the comparison returning a logical array with the same dimension as the input. `&&` is not, returning a single logical.