# Nested ifelse statement doesn't work in R

Tags: r, dplyr

So I'm doing my research for the final assignment at Coursera and the thing is that the nested ifelse statement doesn't work as expected.

Below is the code I've implemented.

```
topic <- topic %>%
  filter(!is.na(fear), !is.na(owngun), !is.na(partyid))

topic <- topic %>%
  mutate(fear = as.numeric(fear)) %>%
  mutate(owngun = as.numeric(owngun))

topic %>%
  group_by(fear, owngun) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

topic <- topic %>%
  mutate(fear_gun = ifelse(fear == 1 && owngun == 1, 1, ifelse(fear == 1 && owngun == 2, 2, ifelse(fear == 2 && owngun == 1, 3, ifelse(fear == 2 && owngun == 2, 3, -1)))))

topic %>%
  group_by(fear_gun) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

And here is the result.
[image: R markdown]

So it seems like the result is not correctly sorted. What's the problem here?

Comment: Why do you need `&&` Try with single `&`

Comment: As a gun enthusiast, I would appreciate a reproducible example. :)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Oh this is just a part of the research topic I'm doing. So the result of the inference would be broader than the thing showed on the code.

Comment: @akrun So "AND" in R is &, not &&?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks. This really helps.

Comment: Can we close as duplicate?

Comment: @zx8754 I'll just leave my own answer cause I'm in danger of being banned.

Comment: @zx8754  Yes, I can close it, if everybody agrees :-)

Comment: @akrun I am not sure if OP is happy to close, I didn't understand his above comment regarding "banned".

Comment: @zx8754  Probably bcz he thinks if all his questions are dupe tagged, his id will be banned for asking more questions.  I don't know the rules either

Comment: I don't see any dupe closed questions in OP's history.