# R logical operation in Which function

Tags: r

`which(df$col=="A" || df$col=="B") returns 1.`

Should not i use logical operation in which function ?

Please advise.

Regards,
Nantha

Comment: It will always be 1 or 0 so long as you use `||`. See `help(Logic)`.  Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking.  `which()` *only* accepts a logical input.

Comment: Maybe you want just one `|`.

Comment: you want to use | instead of ||. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and