# r data frame calculation

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a simple function that has `ifelse`, and would like to use multiple dataframe columns as its input. Here is what I did.

```
year <- c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2017)
month <- c(11, 12, 1, 2)
df <- data.frame(year, month)

test_1 <- function(n, year_2016 = FALSE, year_2017 = FALSE){
  return (  ifelse( (year_2016 == FALSE && year_2017 == FALSE), ifelse(n==24, 'a', 'b'), ifelse(year_2016 == TRUE, ifelse(n==24, 'c', 'd'), ifelse(n==24, 'e', 'f'))))
}

test_2 <- function(n, year_2016 = FALSE){
  return (ifelse(year_2016 == FALSE, ifelse(n==12, 'g', 'h'), ifelse(n==12, 'i', 'j')))
}
```

`test_1` outputs only a single value from the first row, while `test_2` outputs the vector. I was thinking both should be vectors.

If anyone can guide me why this is happening, that would be great. Also, if there's a better way to do this vector calculation, please advice.

Thanks!

=====================================

edit:

Sorry, that I didn't include the line actually running the function. I ran the two followings, which I was hoping to get vectors in both.

```
test_1(df$month, df$year == 2016, df$year == 2017)
test_2(df$month, df$year == 2016)
```

However, when I run it, I get the following.

```
test_1(df$month, df$year == 2016, df$year == 2017)
[1] "d"

test_2(df$month, df$year == 2016)
[1] "j" "i" "h" "h"
```

Comment: Both return a single value when I run them. You are also not using the data frame columns as inputs at all. Can you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: please create a reproducible example so that we can work with it. your function doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Following your edit I would suggest replacing `&&` with `&`. The single ampersand will evaluate each element in the vector, see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and)

Comment: Thank you @mr_jaundo, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to guess a bit here and there are many ways that you could improve this, but you can use this to understand how functions work better and how to use your data frame as input in the function.

```
year <- c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2017)
month <- c(11, 12, 1, 2)
df <- data.frame(year, month)

test_1 <- function(x){
  return (  ifelse( (x[1] != 2016 & x[1] != 2017), ifelse(x[2] == 12, 'a', 'b'), ifelse(x[1] == 2016, ifelse(x[2] == 24, 'c', 'd'), ifelse(x[2] == 24, 'e', 'f'))))
}

test_2 <- function(x){
  return (ifelse(x[1] != 2016, ifelse(x[2] == 12, 'g', 'h'), ifelse(x[2] == 12, 'i', 'j')))
}

##take each row of df and apply the functions
apply(df, 1, test_1)
[1] "d" "d" "f" "f"

apply(df, 1, test_2)
[1] "j" "i" "h" "h"
```

If you have any questions let me know