# Logical not correctly evaluated?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I wondering why my first `if` statement returns `Error` when my input data is an object of class `numeric`?

I have clearly stated for the first `if` statement to only turn on IF the data `class` is `"data.frame"`, but when data class is `numeric`, this first `if` statement return an error! am I missing anything here?

**Update:**

I have changed instances of `&` to `&&` but when data is a `data.frame`, the function doesn't produce any output? For example, run: `standard(mtcars)`

```
standard <- function(data){

  if(class(data) == "data.frame" && ncol(data) > 1){ 

  data[paste0(names(data), ".s")] <- scale(data)
  data
}

 if(class(data) == "data.frame" && ncol(data) == 1){

 colnames(data) <- paste0(names(data), ".s") 
 data <- scale(data)
 data
}  

 if(class(data) != "data.frame"){

d <- as.data.frame(data)  
colnames(d) <- paste0("Var", ncol(d), ".s")
data <- scale(d)
data
   }
}
###### EXAMPLES: #######
standard(mtcars[,2])   ##Problem: `Error in if(class(data) == "data.frame" & ncol(data) > 1)`
standard(mtcars["wt"]) ## OK
standard(mtcars)       ## after UPDATE, doesn't give any output
```

Comment: it's preferred not to ask more than one question in a single SO post ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am I missing anything here?

`&` evaluate both elements while `&&` does not

```r
FALSE && stop("boh")
#R> [1] FALSE
TRUE  && stop("boh")
#R> Error: boh
FALSE &  stop("boh")
#R> Error: boh
```

See `help("Logic")`

> `&` and `&&` indicate logical AND and `|` and `||` indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. **The longer form evaluates left to right** examining only the first element of each vector. **Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined**.

---

## After your edits

You do not get any results because you do not call `return` or use `if else`. See `help("function")` and `help("if")`. Here is a small example

```
f1 <- function(x){
  if(x < 0){
    x <- -1
    x
  }

  if(x > 0){
    x <- 1
    x
  }
}
f1(-1)

f2 <- function(x){
  if(x < 0){
    x <- -1
    x
  }
  else if(x > 0){
    x <- 1
    x
  }
}
f2(-1)
#R> [1] -1

f3 <- function(x){
  if(x < 0){
    x <- -1
    return(x)
  }

  if(x > 0){
    x <- 1
    return(x)
  }
}
f3(-1)
#R> [1] -1
```

Comment: It does if the first element is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** you should use `&&` rather than `&` when doing flow-control, because `&` always evaluates its second argument, while `&&` short-circuits *if the first argument is false*. If the argument isn't a data frame (or matrix) then `ncol(x)` doesn't make sense: see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and/6559049#6559049) for more information.

Go ahead and unpack it with a simple example.

```
x <- 1:5
```

The first part is fine:

```
class(x)  ## "integer"
class(x)=="data.frame"  ## TRUE
```

(although note that you have to be careful, because `class(x)` might be a vector with more than one element: `inherits(x,"data.frame")` is safer).

The second part causes the problem:

```
ncol(x) ## NULL (uh-oh)
ncol(x)>1  ## numeric(0) (uh-oh)
```

Put them together:

```
class(x)=="data.frame" & ncol(x)>1  ## logical(0)
```

What does this do?

```
if (logical(0)) print("hello")
```

> Error in if (logical(0)) print("hello") : argument is of length zero

Comment: I think you might not understand what @BenjaminChristofferson and I are trying to say about "short-circuiting". The problem is that `ncol(x)` doesn't make sense if `x` is not a data frame or matrix, so evaluating this argument (and including it in the logical statement) causes trouble [as you found out]

Comment: Since it wasn't the scope of your question, I didn't look at the function beyond the first logical statement ... Maybe it would help to put some explicit `return()` statements in.