# Using any() vs | in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Why should I use `|` vs `any()` when I'm comparing columns in `dplyr::mutate()`?

And why do they return different answers?

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df  <- data_frame(x = rep(c(T,F,T), 4), y = rep(c(T,F,T, F), 3), allF  = F, allT = T)

 df %>%
     mutate( 
          withpipe = x | y # returns expected results by row
        , usingany = any(c(x,y)) # returns TRUE for every row
     )
```

What's going on here and why should I use one way of comparing values over another?

Comment: Your code doesn't run - must be a missing bracket somewhere.

Comment: It's the same difference in vectorization as `+` and `sum`. Related and slightly more complicated: [the difference between `|` and `||`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and)

Comment: Fixed typo in code example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the two is how the answer is calculated:

- for `|`, elements are compared row-wise and boolean logic is used to return the proper value. In the example above each x and y pair are compared to each other and a logical value is returned for each pair, resulting in 12 different answers, one for each row of the data frame.
- `any()`, on the other hand, looks at the entire vector and returns a single value. In the above example, the mutate line that calculates the new `usingany` column is basically doing this: `any(c(df$x, df$y))`, which will return `TRUE` because there's at least one `TRUE` value in either `df$x` or `df$y`. That single value is then assigned to every row of the data frame.

You can see this in action using the other columns in your data frame:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(
        usingany = any(c(x,y)) # returns all TRUE
      , allfany  = any(allF)   # returns all FALSE because every value in df$allF is FALSE
    )
```

To answer when you should use which: use `|` when you want to compare elements row-wise. Use `any()` when you want a universal answer about the entire data frame.

TLDR, when using `dplyr::mutate()`, you're usually going to want to use `|`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`rowwise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html).

```
df  <- data_frame(x = rep(c(T,F,T), 4), y = rep(c(T,F,T, F), 3), allF  = F, allT = T)

 df %>%
     rowwise() %>%
     mutate(x_or_y = any(x,y))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5  
    x     y     allF  allT  x_or_y  
    <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>   
  1 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   
  2 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE  
  3 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   
  4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE   
  5 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   
  6 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE   
  7 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   
  8 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE  
  9 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  
 10 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  
 11 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  
 12 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR (update)**:
`if_any`is the cleanest replacement for `any()` in rowwise operations with dplyr. See below.

**You can use both the OR operator `|` or `any()`**

It is the same thing when comparing `&`and `all()`.

As suggested, you must take into account that **`|`is vectorized, while `any()` is not**

In order to use any() the same way, you must **group the data rowwise**, so you can call an equivalent of `any(current_row)`. This can be done with `purrr::pmap` or `dplyr::rowwise`.

But **`dplyr::if_any`** looks a lot cleaner.

Se the code below for a comparison of all methods:

```
df%>%mutate(
    row_OR=x|y,
    row_pmap_any=pmap_lgl(select(.,c(x,y)), any),
    with_if_any = if_any(c(x,y)))%>%
    rowwise()%>%
    mutate(
    row_rowwise_any=any(c_across(c(x,y))))

# A tibble: 12 × 8
# Rowwise: 
   x     y     allF  allT  row_OR row_pmap_any with_if_any row_rowwise_any
   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl>        <lgl>       <lgl>          
 1 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
 2 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE  FALSE        FALSE       FALSE          
 3 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
 4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
 5 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
 6 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
 7 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
 8 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE  FALSE        FALSE       FALSE          
 9 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
10 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
11 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE           
12 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         TRUE        TRUE
```

All methods work, and I did not find much difference in performance.