# In dplyr, mutate a logical column where any of a set of other logical columns are true

Tags: r, dplyr, any

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
typ1  typ2  typ3
   T     T     F
   F     F     F
   T     F     F
```

and I want mutate a 4th logical column determining if any of the other three are TRUE, so {T, F, T}.

`mutate(isAnyType = any(typ1, typ2, typ3))` seems to be using the whole columns, when I would like to use the information per row. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `reduce` with `|` to check if there are any TRUE elements in each row

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(isAnyType = reduce(., `|`))
```

---

Or using `rowSums` in `base R`

```
df1$isAnyType <- rowSums(df1) > 0
```

---

Or another option is `pmap`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(isAnyType = pmap_lgl(., ~ any(c(...)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(typ1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), typ2 = c(TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE), typ3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer can be found here:
[Using any() vs | in dplyr::mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259361/using-any-vs-in-dplyrmutate)

Rather than any(), which utilizes the whole dataframe, I can just use the OR operator, so that `mutate(isAnyType = typ1 |typ2 |typ3))` would work

Answer (score 0):

If you take advantage of the boolean values being stored as T = 1, F = 0, I believe you could use the rowSums() function to evaluate instances of T/F row-wise. Is this what you're looking for?

input:

```
df <- data.frame(typ1 = c(T, F, T),
                 typ2 = c(T,F, F),
                 typ3 = c(F, F, F))
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(typ4 = ifelse(rowSums(df) ==0, F, T))
```

output:

```
   typ1  typ2  typ3  typ4
1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```