# How do I deal with an Ifelse condition that is not giving me an error but is also not giving me any change in my output?

Tags: r, kaggle

I have been working with the Titanic dataset from Kaggle. I have been trying to use an ifelse condition with an aim to do some feature engineering work but unfortunately I have been struck with my if else condition which is not producing an error but at the same time not working at all. What am I doing wrong and how do I deal with it?
Here is my code:

```
if(train$titles=="Dr" && train$Sex=="male"){
  train$titles<-"Mr"
}else if(train$titles=="Dr" && train$Sex=="female"){
  train$titles<-"Mrs"
}
```

Here is my output which is the same before and after:

```
> table(train$titles)

  Mr  Mrs   Dr Miss 
 571  128    7  185
```

Is this because I have left out the final else condition?

The thing is if the conditions in the if else don't match at all then I don't want to change the values in the column(i.e. I want them to be as it is).
What do I do?

Comment: Actually tried it but I am getting a warning message. Here it is:           Warning messages:
1: In if (train$titles == "Dr" & train$Sex == "male") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (train$titles == "Dr" & train$Sex == "female") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Use `ifelse` instead of `if` because the former is vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

Try logical indexing.

```
inx <- train$titles == "Dr"
train$titles[inx & train$sex == "male"] <- "Mr"
train$titles[inx & train$sex == "female"] <- "Mrs"
```

**Also,** like user [Dan Y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573108/dan-y) said in a comment to the question, repeated here because sometimes comments are deleted,

> Use ifelse instead of if because the former is vectorized.

A `ifelse` solution still using `inx` as defined above could be

```
train$titles[inx] <- ifelse(train$sex[inx] == "male", "Mr", "Mrs")
```

I am using `inx` to avoid a longer code line. You can put the definition of `inx` in the indices of the `ifelse` if you prefer.

Comment: Same problem again. Doesn't produce an error but the output is the same.

Comment: @TheAsipiringone Are you sure it's `"male"` and `"female"`, not `"Male"` and `"Female"`?

Comment: Yeah sure! Double checked it. It is "male" and "female"

Comment: 1) How much is `sum(inx)`? 2) Maybe there are white spaces before or after some `"Dr"`, `"male/"female"`. if you run `train$titles <- trimws(train$titles)` and `train$sex <- trimws(train$sex)` before, does it change anything?

Comment: sum(inx) is giving me an output of  7. When I output it, it is showing me 881 TRUE/FALSE values. Tried trimws too but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `ifelse`, which is a vectorised form and will do what you want:

```
train$titles = ifelse(train$titles=="Dr" & train$Sex=="male", "Mr", "Mrs")
```

Also, beware of the [difference between `&` and `&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and).

If you have multiple cases, you can nest multiple `ifelse` statements. You may also be interested in `dplyr::case_when`.

Comment: Actually I have got four different categories in the ordinal variable titles:"Mr","Mrs","Miss" and "Doctor". So using this all of them get changed into "Mr" and "Mrs" which I don't wan't. I want the "Miss" to remain as it is.

Comment: Right, so you need to nest them: `ifelse(x== "Foo", "bar", ifelse(x == "baz", "blah", ifelse(...` which obviously gets clunky pretty fast, hence the use of `case_when` or an alternative formulation of the problem using `match`.