# R Shiny - How to display feedback message if two inputs have the same value (using shinyFeedback)

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I have two selectizeInputs (`state1` and `state2`) in my app that have the same set of choices. When the user clicks the actionButton, I would like to compare the values of `state1` and `state2` and display a feedback message to the user if they are the same.

Both selectizeInputs are initialised with the placeholder "Search by name". If I change the value of one input for the first time and leave the value of the other unchanged at its placeholder value, then clicking the action button triggers the feedback message:

[image]
[image]

This is puzzling to me because the message should only be displayed if `state1` and `state2` are the same.

Here is the code to reproduce the above:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)


ui <- fluidPage(shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
                selectizeInput('state1', 'Select state 1', choices = state.name, 
                               multiple = T, 
                               options = list(placeholder = "Search by name", maxItems = 1)),

                selectizeInput('state2', 'Select state 2', choices = state.name, 
                               multiple = T, 
                               options = list(placeholder = "Search by name", maxItems = 1)),

                actionButton("click", "Click"),

                textOutput("states")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values = reactiveValues(states = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$click, {

    feedbackDanger("state1", input$state1 == input$state2, "")

    feedbackDanger("state2", input$state2 == input$state1, "State 1 and state 2 cannot be the same.")

    req(!is.null(input$state1), !is.null(input$state2), input$state1 != input$state2)

    values$states <- paste(input$state1, input$state2)

  })

  output$states <- renderText({

    values$states

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I think this may have something to do with using multiple = T and maxItems = 1 in the selectizeInputs or with the way I have written the trigger conditions but I don't understand why they are wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit: 2019-02-13

The bug has been resolved in the GitHub version of `shinyFeeback`. Your original code should work if you install the package from GitHub:

```
devtools::install_github("merlinoa/shinyFeedback")
```

--

#### Issue

You were thinking along the right lines! In your first example, `input$state1` is "Alaska" and `input$state2` is empty. The initial value of `selectizeInput` with `multiple = T` is `NULL`.

When your `feedbackDanger` condition compares the two values, the result is an empty logical:

```
> "Alaska" == NULL
logical(0)
```

The empty logical is passed as an empty object to the `shinyFeedback` javascript function [`checkFeedback`](https://github.com/merlinoa/shinyFeedback/blob/388b8c9e10a015fe2d95b5808e83fa5f8f342f12/inst/srcjs/checkFeedback.js). Empty objects are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), and so are "considered `true` when encountered in a Boolean context." So when `checkFeedback` evaluates the value:

```
if (message.condition) {

   ....
```

the statement returns `true` and the `feedbackDanger` message is displayed.

#### Solution

A simple solution would be to first check if either value is `NULL` and then check for equality, like this:

```
((!is.null(input$state1) & !is.null(input$state2)) && (input$state1 == input$state2))
```

**Edit:** We use `&&` so that we evaluate if either value is `NULL` first. Only if neither value is `NULL`, do we then evaluate whether the values are the same. Evaluating in this order avoids sending the empty logical to the JS function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559049/8099834) for more information on `&` vs `&&`. **/Edit**

A full working solution would look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)


ui <- fluidPage(shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
                selectizeInput('state1', 'Select state 1', choices = state.name, 
                               multiple = T, 
                               options = list(placeholder = "Search by name", maxItems = 1)),

                selectizeInput('state2', 'Select state 2', choices = state.name, 
                               multiple = T, 
                               options = list(placeholder = "Search by name", maxItems = 1)),

                actionButton("click", "Click"),

                textOutput("states")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    values = reactiveValues(states = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$click, {
        condition <- ((!is.null(input$state1) & !is.null(input$state2)) && (input$state1 == input$state2))

        feedbackDanger("state1", condition, "")

        feedbackDanger("state2", condition, "State 1 and state 2 cannot be the same.")

        req(!is.null(input$state1), !is.null(input$state2), input$state1 != input$state2)

        values$states <- paste(input$state1, input$state2)

    })

    output$states <- renderText({

        values$states

    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! I'm not familiar with "truthy" values so I really appreciate it. Would it please be possible to explain why you chose to use && instead of & for the second comparison?

Comment: @user51462 You're welcome! Happy to help. I added an explanation of using && instead of & to the answer. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: @user51462 the bug was fixed. if you download the package directly from GitHub, your original code should work. I edited the answer to reflect this