# Omitting NAs and empty data frames with map_if

Tags: r, predicate, purrr

I'm working with a tibble like below:

```
ex <- structure(list(rowid = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L), timestamp = structure(c(1502480694.03336, 
1502480695.44736, 1502480696.03336, 1502480703.99836, 1502480706.19936
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(32L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), var1 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    var2 = c(0, 50, 29.7, 51, 70.8), var3 = c(NA, 26.3, 24, 20.5, 
    12), order = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), bfr = list(NA, structure(list(
        rowid = integer(0), timestamp = structure(numeric(0), class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = integer(0), var1 = structure(integer(0), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
        var2 = numeric(0), var3 = numeric(0), order = integer(0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = integer(0)), structure(list(
        rowid = 5L, timestamp = structure(1502480695.44736, class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = 1L, var1 = structure(NA_integer_, .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
        var2 = 50, var3 = 26.3, order = 1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), structure(list(
        rowid = 5:8, timestamp = structure(c(1502480695.44736, 
        1502480696.03336, 1502480699.03336, 1502480701.03336), class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), var1 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
        var2 = c(50, 29.7, 52.8, 44), var3 = c(26.3, 24, 8.9, 
        12.4), order = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)), structure(list(
        rowid = 5:9, timestamp = structure(c(1502480695.44736, 
        1502480696.03336, 1502480699.03336, 1502480701.03336, 
        1502480703.99836), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
        cat = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), var1 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
        var2 = c(50, 29.7, 52.8, 44, 51), var3 = c(26.3, 24, 
        8.9, 12.4, 20.5), order = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L)))), row.names = c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 9L, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to summarise nested tibbles in column `bfr` with `map`. To omit unnecessary calculations, I want to go with `map_if` which would skip the row when `bfr` contains less than 2 rows with `cat == 1`. However due to presence of `NA`s and empty tibbles in `bfr` column, I'm struggling with writing appropriate predicate function. Here's my attempt:

```
more_than <- function(df){
  if (nrow(df) == 0 | is.na(df)) return(FALSE)

  n <- df %>% 
    summarise(sum(cat == 1)) %>% 
    as.numeric()

  return(n > 2)
}

ex %>% 
  mutate(mean_var2 = map_if(bfr, more_than, 
                            ~.x %>% summarise(mean_var2 = mean(var2))))
```

which results in:

> Error in if (nrow(df) == 0 | is.na(df)) return(FALSE) : 
>     argument is of length zero

How can I deal with the presence of both `NA`s and empty tibbles to write appropriate predicate function?

Comment: The issue is with `is.na(df)`, which does the NA check on the whole data while nrow is a single output

Comment: Also, in the `more_than`, you are doing some other calculation which you are not getting as output in the `mean_var2`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your first comment - could you possibly elaborate in your answer? `more_than` is just a predicate to avoid unneccesary calculations for some elements of `bfr` column.

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to get the `mean` of 'var2'  column, check the `list` elements are either `data.frame` or `tibble` (in this case it is a tibble) and then do the `summarise`

```
out <-  ex %>% 
           mutate(mean_var2 = map_if(bfr, is.tibble, ~ 
             .x %>% 
                summarise(mean_var2 = mean(var2, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

---

If we also need to check `sum(cat ==1) > 2`

```
more_than <- function(df){
i1 <- is_tibble(df)
if(i1) {
   n <- df %>% 
    summarise(v1 = sum(cat == 1))  %>%
    pull(v1) 
    }

    i1 && (n > 2)


}
ex %>%
  mutate(mean_var2 = map_if(bfr, more_than, ~
      .x %>%
         summarise(mean_var2 = mean(var2, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

---

The reason why `is.na` is not working is because it checks for each dataset and in some of them it is a `tibble` and this returns a logical `matrix`, while `if/else` expects a single TRUE/FALSE to return.  For e.g.

```
(3 == 4) & (cbind(3:5, 1:3) == 3)
```

yields a different output

One option is to use `&&`, so that it evaluates the rhs condition only if the first condition is TRUE and thereby avoiding unncessary evaluation

```
(3 == 4) && (cbind(3:5, 1:3) == 3)
#[1] FALSE
```

---

In the OP's original function, if we replace the `|` with `||` it should work fine

```
more_than <- function(df){
  if (nrow(df) == 0 || is.na(df)) return(FALSE)

  n <- df %>% 
    summarise(sum(cat == 1)) %>% 
    as.numeric()

  return(n > 2)
}
```

#### Update

If we want to return NA for those cases that are not met

```
ex %>%
    mutate(mean_var2 = map_dbl(bfr, ~ 
    if(is_tibble(.x) && sum(.x$cat == 1) > 2) mean(.x$var2, na.rm = TRUE) else NA))
```

---

Or another option is to use `possibly` (similar to `tryCatch`)

```
posmean <- possibly(function(dat) if(sum(dat$cat == 1) > 2) 
     mean(dat$var2, na.rm  = TRUE) else NA_real_, otherwise = NA_real_)
ex %>% 
     mutate(mean_var2 = map_dbl(bfr, posmean))
```

Comment: Then, we don't check for additional condition regarding `cat == 1`, which results in massive overload on the original data.

Comment: @jakes Here, we are interested in the column 'var2', so, it is more direct to check whether it is a data.frame or not

Comment: Mean of `var2` is used as surogate in order to avoid showing original calculations to be performed which involve number of elements in nested data frames and at the same time, making this post unnecessarily long. Checking if a tibble contains more than 2 values of 1 in `cat` column is crucial, so more complicated predicate function is needed.

Comment: @jakes Are you saying that only if sum(cat) > 2, then the `mean` should be calculated or else `NA

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant here.

Comment: @jakes I updated the post.  Note that `map_if` skips the calculation on those list elements that are not TRUE

Comment: Great! It works now. I wonder why `is.na` didn't work though. Could you possibly elaborate on your first comment under my post in some spare time? Thanks!

Comment: @jakes I added some explanation

Comment: Thanks! I noticed something else - if condition `n > 2` is not met, `mean_var2` results in original tibble and not NA as intended (see row 3). Any idea how to correct that without checking if `bfr == mean_var2` at the end?

Comment: @jakes I noticed that.  It is the reason I said `map_if` skips the calculation

Comment: `ex %>%   mutate(mean_var2 = map_if(bfr, more_than,  ~.x %>%summarise(mean_var2 = mean(var2,na.rm = TRUE)),.else = NA_integer_))` define `.else` will do the trick, `.else 
A function applied to elements of .x for which .p returns FALSE.`

Comment: @jakes You can use `ex %>% mutate(mean_var2 = map_dbl(bfr, ~ if(is_tibble(.x) && sum(.x$cat == 1) > 2) mean(.x$var2, na.rm = TRUE) else NA))`

Comment: @A.Suliman  That is a nice option.  I didn't know that.  YOu should post it as an answer

Comment: @A.Suliman  I tested it, but it is giving me `NULL` instead of `NA`. any thoughts?

Comment: @akrun we need a function for `.else`, I tested with `dplyr::first` and it works as expected hence I define a function like `foo <- function(x){return(NA)}`, so we endup with `ex %>% mutate(mean_var2 = map_if(bfr, more_than,  ~.x %>% summarise(mean_var2 = mean(var2,na.rm = TRUE)),.else = foo)) %>% select(mean_var2)` of course you will find something better. One more option `.else = ~return(NA)`

Comment: @A.Suliman  Can you post as an answer, because it would be better for others as well to get more insights from this

Answer (score 2):

first, we need to check for NA's with `||` "see the difference between | and || [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and)" before we check *nrow*. Then we need `.else` which is:

> .else  A function applied to elements of .x for which .p returns FALSE.

when `more_than` returns FLASE

```
more_than <- function(df){
 # browser()
  if (all(is.na(df)) || nrow(df) == 0) return(FALSE)

     n <- df %>%
       summarise(sum(cat == 1)) %>%
       as.numeric()

     return(n > 2)
}

ex %>% 
mutate(mean_var2 = map_if(bfr, more_than, 
                          ~.x %>% summarise(mean_var2 = mean(var2,na.rm = TRUE)),
                         .else = ~return(NA))) %>% 
select(mean_var2)

   mean_var2
1        NA
2        NA
3        NA
4    44.125
5      45.5
```