# Subsetting with Multiple Conditions

Tags: r

I’m having trouble putting two conditions into a subset. The result is a whole bunch of NA.

```
> df[(df$col > 0) && (df$col < 4), ]
```

Comment: Use `&`, not `&&`, so `df[(df$col > 0) & (df$col < 4), ]`. The former is vectorized; the latter isn't and short-circuits. (Use it in `if` conditions.) Docs: `?\`&&\``

Comment: @alistaire Thanks! That did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the space after ',' and you only need one '&'.

```
df[df$col > 0 & df$col < 4,]
```

You may be getting NA 'cause you want OR (|) instead of AND (&).

Comment: *"Drop the space after ',' "* The extra whitespace has nothing to do with the issue. in fact, for readability and to be consistent with common R coding style recommendations, it's better to keep the whitespace after the comma. You are correct in pointing out the difference between `&` and `&&`. See also [Boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and).

Comment: The single ampersand did the trick. Thanks! (White space had no effect.)