# Find different kinds of missing values with one command - syntax error?

Tags: r, filter, subset

I seem to have a syntactical error that I am not able to find.

I have a column of a data frame seperated in a list called `column`. I want to find all the missing values in this column. However, for some reason I get the whole list returned.

Here's my attempt

```
> length(column)
[1] 712789
> length(column[column == ""])
[1] 24181
> length(column[column == "0"])
[1] 24181
> length(column[is.na(column)])
[1] 24181
> length(column[column == "" || column == "0" || is.na(column)])
[1] 712789
```

This is strange. I would expect the last subset to be `24181` as well. Even if all the subsets above would refer to different elements, the output shouldn't be greater than `24181 x 3 = 72549`. Instead, the whole list is part of the subset.

What am I doing wrong?

[edit]
For couriosity I tried any combination of two (instead of three) subsets: the result also was `712789` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of code should use `|` rather than `||`.

A single vertical bar works with vectors but the double bar only works with scalars.

Suppose the ith value of column is "".  Then the ith value of the result is `"" == "" | "" == "0" | is.na("")` which equals TRUE | FALSE | FALSE which is TRUE.

Suppose the ith value of column is "0".  Then the ith value of the result is `"0" == "" | "0" == "0" | is.na("0")` which equals FALSE | TRUE | FALSE which is TRUE.

Suppose the ith value of column is NA.  Then the ith value of the result is `NA == "" | NA == "0" | is.na(NA)` which equals NA | NA | TRUE which is TRUE.

Thus the ith value of the result is TRUE for any of the conditions.  It is FALSE otherwise.

For more information see:
[Boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and)

Comment: Thank you! Shocking, I never realised the big difference between bitwise and logical operators :O

Comment: But just for couriosity: why does that make a difference?

Comment: yes, this I understand so `||` is faster (which probably is the reason why I used it all the time). But how can `||` ever evaluate to `TRUE` when `|` evaluates to false?

Comment: ok, now I see there is a difference between `|` and `||`. Thank you. But I did run `length(column[column == "" | column == "0" | is.na(column)])` again and didn't receive an error but just the expected return of `24181`. Should I be worried about this? Sorry to bug you. I just don't get the point although you are obviously right :)

Comment: Have moved comments to answer.

Comment: Thank you! I think I kind of get it now. Also the link helped!