# Trouble with nested ifelse statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization

I'm trying to run a nested ifelse statement in R.  Here's a look at the structure of my data using the glimpse() function from the tidyverse:

```
Rows: 22,104
Columns: 9
$ `Formation/Locality`    <chr> "Montmartre", "Montmartre", "Montmartre", "Fur", "Me...
$ Location                <chr> "Ile-de-France Region, France", "Ile-de-France Regio...
$ Environment             <chr> "terrestrial", "terrestrial", "terrestrial", "offsho...
$ `Palaeolongitude(N/-S)` <dbl> 47.4, 47.4, 47.4, 52.3, 46.9, 42.9, 47.5, 46.9, 46.2...
$ `Palaeolatitude(E/-W)`  <dbl> 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 5.4, 4.8, 1.9, -5.2, 4.8, -93.6, -111...
$ TaxonomicLevel          <chr> "Order", "Order", "Order", "Order", "Order", "Order"...
$ TaxonomicName           <chr> "Upupiformes", "Upupiformes", "Upupiformes", "Trogon...
$ MinMax                  <chr> "MaxMa", "MaxMa", "MaxMa", "MaxMa", "MaxMa", "MaxMa"...
$ Age                     <dbl> 37.2, 37.2, 37.2, 55.8, 48.6, 37.2, 48.6, 48.6, 55.8...
```

I'm trying to get R to look at the `Age` column and if the value is within a certain range, for it to put the geological age name into a new column called `AgeName`.  If the value is not within the range, I want it to move on to the next age range and so on and so forth.  Here's my code so far:

```
pbdb_tidyish$AgeName <- ifelse(56>=pbdb_tidyish$Age&&47.8<pbdb_tidyish$Age,
                               "Ypresian",
                               ifelse(47.8>=pbdb_tidyish$Age&&41.2<pbdb_tidyish$Age,
                                      "Lutetian",
                                      ifelse(41.2>=pbdb_tidyish$Age&&37.8<pbdb_tidyish$Age,
                                             "Bartonian",
                                             ifelse(37.8>=pbdb_tidyish$Age&&33.9<=pbdb_tidyish$Age,
                                                    "Priabonian",NA))))
```

When I run this code, it creates the new column but fills the whole column with `"Priabonian"` so the dataset now looks like this:

```
Rows: 22,104
Columns: 10
$ `Formation/Locality`    <chr> "Montmartre", "Montmartre", "Montmartre", "Fur", "Me...
$ Location                <chr> "Ile-de-France Region, France", "Ile-de-France Regio...
$ Environment             <chr> "terrestrial", "terrestrial", "terrestrial", "offsho...
$ `Palaeolongitude(N/-S)` <dbl> 47.4, 47.4, 47.4, 52.3, 46.9, 42.9, 47.5, 46.9, 46.2...
$ `Palaeolatitude(E/-W)`  <dbl> 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 5.4, 4.8, 1.9, -5.2, 4.8, -93.6, -111...
$ TaxonomicLevel          <chr> "Order", "Order", "Order", "Order", "Order", "Order"...
$ TaxonomicName           <chr> "Upupiformes", "Upupiformes", "Upupiformes", "Trogon...
$ MinMax                  <chr> "MaxMa", "MaxMa", "MaxMa", "MaxMa", "MaxMa", "MaxMa"...
$ Age                     <dbl> 37.2, 37.2, 37.2, 55.8, 48.6, 37.2, 48.6, 48.6, 55.8...
$ AgeName                 <chr> "Priabonian", "Priabonian", "Priabonian", "Priabonia...
```

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? I think it's just looking at the first `Age` value, running the ifelse statement then filling the whole column with the result of that as opposed to moving on to the next row.

Thanks,

Carolina

Comment: Why `56>=pbdb_tidyish$Age` and not `pbdb_tidyish$Age >= 56`?

Comment: Perhaps `case_when` is a better choice.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest using more spaces in your code - itwillbemucheasiertoreadanddebug. Many style guides recommend spaces between binary operators, e.g., `56>=pbdb_tidyish$Age&&47.8<pbdb_tidyish$Age` becomes `56 >= pbdb_tidyish$Age && 47.8 < pbdb_tidyish$Age`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without data it is unclear whether this is the only error but you should not use `&&` here since it is not vectorized. That means, it only checks the value in the first row, returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, based on this single observation only, and recycles this value.

Use `&` instead.

For a comparison see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559049/8107362)

Comment: Yes that's all there was to it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think whenever you find yourself writing nested `ifelse` statements you should stop and ask yourself whether there might be a better way to achieve what you're trying to do. For example, the following single function call does what you are trying to achieve, and is easier to understand and maintain:

```
cut(pdb$tidyish, breaks = c(33.9, 37.8, 41.2, 47.8, 56),
    labels = c("Priabonian", "Bartonian", "Lutetian", "Ypresian"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already using the tidyverse, you should make yourself familiar with `case_when`:

```
pbdb_tidyish <- pbdb_tidyish %>%
  mutate(AgeName = case_when(
    (Age >= 33.9 & Age <= 37.8) ~ 'Priabonian',
    (Age > 37.8 & Age <= 41.2) ~ 'Bartonian',
    (Age > 41.2 & Age <= 47.8) ~ 'Lutetian',
    (Age > 47.8 & Age <= 56) ~ 'Ypresian',
  ))
```