# R: How to filter column as long as it contains combination of values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like this:

```
VisitID | Item |
1       | A    |
1       | B    |
1       | C    |
1       | D    |
2       | A    |
2       | D    |
2       | B    |
3       | B    |
3       | C    |
4       | D    |
4       | C    |
```

In R, how do I filter for VisitIDs as long as they contain Item A & B?
Expected Outcome:

```
VisitID | Item |
1       | A    |
1       | B    |
1       | C    |
1       | D    |
2       | A    |
2       | D    |
2       | B    |
```

I tried `df %>% group_by(VisitID) %>% filter(any(Item == 'A' & Item == 'B'))` but it doesn't work..

```
df <- read_delim("ID | Item 
1  | A    
1  | B    
2  | A    
3  | B    
1  | C    
4  | C    
5  | B    
3  | A    
4  | A    
5  | D", delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try `filter(any(Item == 'A')  & any(Item == 'B'))` It's not possible for an Item to be both A and B at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want both "A" and "B" you can use `all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(VisitID) %>% filter(all(c("A", "B") %in% Item))

#  VisitID Item 
#    <int> <chr>
#1       1 A    
#2       1 B    
#3       1 C    
#4       1 D    
#5       2 A    
#6       2 D    
#7       2 B
```

OR if you want to use `any` use them separately.

```
df %>% group_by(VisitID) %>% filter(any(Item == 'A') && any(Item == 'B'))
```

Comment: changed `&` to `&&`, but I'm not 100% sure that's right. please redact if I'm mistaken

Comment: That's correct since `any` would return a single `TRUE`/`FALSE` . Thanks @MichaelChirico

Comment: could someone explain on the use of && instead of &?

Comment: @spidermarn `&&` works for scalars (basically, `TRUE` or `FALSE` _only_) -- `&` works for vectors, i.e., sequences of `TRUE`/`FALSE`/`NA`. Because `&&` is a special case it works much faster when it's appropriate

Comment: You can also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and

Answer (score 0):

An otion with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(c("A", "B") %in% Item)], VisitID]
```