# How to continue a while loop while the condition is false in r?

Tags: r, while-loop, boolean, conditional-statements

I have this while loop:

```
while (abs(B-left)<INFSMALL | abs(B-right)<INFSMALL) {
...
}
```

I want it to run while the above condition is FALSE. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of:

1. Negate the entire conditional by wrapping it with `!(.)`, as in

   ```r
   while (!(abs(B-left) < INFSMALL || abs(B-right) < INFSMALL)) {
   ...
   }
   ```
2. Negate the components inside, and change from OR to AND:

   ```r
   while (abs(B-left) >= INFSMALL && abs(B-right) >= INFSMALL) {
   ...
   }
   ```

You should be using `||` instead of `|`, see [Boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/3358272). The flow-control functions `if` and `while` need the conditional to be length-1 exactly, not 0, no more than 1. While `|` will produce a vector of length 1 if all of the arguments are length 1, there are two reasons this is still a bad idea:

1. *Short-circuiting*: in general, if the first (of multiple, chained) conditional suggests that the second (and beyond) conditional does not matter, than short-circuiting means it will not evaluate them. Without predefining `aa`, for instance, compare

   ```r
   exists("aa") && aa > 0
   # [1] FALSE
   exists("aa") & aa > 0
   # Error: object 'aa' not found
   ```
2. *Declarative code*: the control-flow `while` must only take length-1, make sure you know this going in. It's perhaps a little bit of style, so more-so #1 above.