# Suggestions for Shortening code when using Boolean Operator "|" when preparing data in R

Tags: r, boolean-logic

As with many things in R, there are multiple ways to test whether set of criteria contains desired values.
I am looking for suggestions to reduce the amount of code indicated below. The desired
result is provided

```
library(dplyr)
df.test=data.frame(
  L=c("A","B","C"),
  num=c(1,2,3),
  num2=c(1,2,3)
)
```

what works, but a little cumbersome.

```
myfun.=function(L){
     case_when(
        L == "A" | L ==  "B" | L ==  "C"  ~ 1 # this is the conditional statement i am seeking to reduce
      )
  }
```

apply function

```
df.test %>% mutate(
  +     result=myfun.(L)
  +    )
```

desired output

```
L num num2 result
1 A   1    1      1
2 B   2    2      1
3 C   3    3      1
```

what i have tried but doesn't work.

```
l=list(c("A","B","C"))

myfun.=function(L){
  case_when(
    L == all( L %in% l)  ~ 1
  )
}
```

i looked at several sources including the 'Hands on Programing Guide with R' (pp. 131 ) and the following post [Boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and) and wasnt able to find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `%in%` instead of `==`

```
library(dplyr)
df.test %>% 
     mutate(result =  +(L %in% c("A", "B", "C")))
```

-output

```
 L num num2 result
1 A   1    1      1
2 B   2    2      1
3 C   3    3      1
```