# Nested if statement within for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I need to fix this if statement nested in a for loop.

###### Create Column: GroupAllFemalesBoysLived

###### This column looks at all ticket numbers that have the same value and then returns a 1 if all females (women and children) and all boys (male children) survived within that group (all ticket numbers are the same), else returns a 0.

```r
for (loopitem in titanic1$Ticket) {
    if (titanic1$Gender == "Male Child" & titanic1$Survived == 1 && 
        titanic1$Gender == "Female Child" & titanic1$Survived == 1 && 
        titanic1$Gender == "Female Adult" & titanic1$Survived == 1) 
        {titanic1$GroupAllFemalesBoysLived = 1} 
    else {titanic1$GroupAllFemalesBoysLived = 0}
}
```

I am getting this error message:

> Warning message in if (titanic1$Gender == "Male Child" &
> titanic1$Survived == 1 && : “the condition has length > 1 and only the
> first element will be used”

Comment: Why are you mixing `&` with `&&`? And the `for` loop variable `loopitem` is not used.

Comment: In R language `&` is vectorized while `&&` is not. The same is with `|` and `||`. See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a loop, R is vectorized.

```
cond1 <- titanic1$Survived == 1
cond2 <- titanic1$Gender %in% c("Male Child", "Female Child","Female Adult")
titanic1$GroupAllFemalesBoysLived <- cond1 & cond2
```