# R: how do I subset a dataframe based on two conditions in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to subset the `d` dataframe by the `Profile` column in the `ann` dataframe, whereby I only want to keep rows with `Profile` variable `BP`. The `FID` column in `d` is the same as the `Database_ID` column in `ann`.

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
bdf <- d %>% semi_join(ann %>% filter(Profile=="BP"||Profile=="Unaffected control"), by=c("FID"="Database_ID"))
```

Result:

```
[1] FID IID SOL C1  C2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I'm getting empty rows.

`d` dataframe

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(FID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13", "AC14", 
"AC15", "AC17", "AC18", "AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21", "AC22", 
"AC23", "AC24", "AC25", "AC26", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2", "AC30", 
"AC31", "AC32", "AC33", "AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC37", "AC38", 
"AC39", "AC3", "AC40", "AC41", "AC42", "AC43", "AC45", "AC46", 
"AC47", "AC48", "AC49", "AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53", "AC54", 
"AC55", "AC56", "AC57", "AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61", "AC62", 
"AC63", "AC64", "AC65", "AC66", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6", "AC70", 
"AC71", "AC72", "AC73", "AC74", "AC75", "AC76", "AC77", "AC78", 
"AC79", "AC7", "AC80", "AC81", "AC82", "AC83", "AC84", "AC86", 
"AC87", "AC88", "AC89", "AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC92", "AC9", 
"AC100", "AC101", "AC102", "AC103", "AC104", "AC105", "AC16", 
"AC68", "AC93", "AC94", "AC95", "AC96", "AC97", "AC99", "DE10", 
"DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", "DE16", "DE17", "DE18", "DE19", 
"DE1", "DE20", "DE21", "DE22", "DE23", "DE25", "DE26", "DE27", 
"DE2", "DE33", "DE34", "DE35", "DE36", "DE37", "DE38", "DE39", 
"DE3", "DE40", "DE41", "DE42", "DE44", "DE45", "DE46", "DE47", 
"DE48", "DE49", "DE4", "DE50", "DE51", "DE52", "DE53", "DE54", 
"DE55", "DE56", "DE57", "DE58", "DE59", "DE60", "DE7", "DE9", 
"DE29", "DE30", "DE32", "DE43", "DE5"), IID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), SOL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), C1 = c(-0.00385609, 0.0101138, -0.0146168, -0.0218236, -0.0134745, 
-0.017089, 0.0152448, 0.0134359, 0.00540102, -0.0125389, 0.00463956, 
-0.00416079, -0.000325898, 0.0132781, 0.0130666, 0.00718399, 
-0.0051912, -0.0227934, 0.0364974, -0.0180301, -0.0226556, -0.00585266, 
0.0258924, -0.00994298, -0.00380612, 0.0187883, 0.0103367, 0.00747272, 
0.0191431, -0.00501846, -0.00118336, 0.0361201, 0.00830498, 0.00380194, 
0.00667686, -0.000441697, -0.00170991, -0.0281008, -0.00424591, 
0.0213412, 0.00261405, 0.016154, 0.0098956, 0.0141544, 0.0367203, 
0.0144693, 0.0256731, -0.00218851, 0.0204603, -0.000603019, -0.00504176, 
-0.00917368, 0.00237875, 0.0175946, 0.0188388, 0.0368965, -0.00408476, 
0.00871812, -0.00851917, 0.0252035, -0.00915532, 0.0223745, 0.016866, 
0.026825, 0.0366276, 0.0540474, 0.0386237, 0.0029996, 0.0207176, 
0.0177353, -0.0066377, 0.0343811, 0.0282509, 0.00526683, 0.0459516, 
0.00976286, 0.0259005, -0.00104822, -0.012696, 0.0134071, 0.0231658, 
0.00359455, 0.0194968, -0.000936478, -0.0029218, -0.0058512, 
-0.000837274, -0.0129465, -0.0102079, -0.00559039, 0.0118966, 
0.00147658, 0.0120396, -0.0104779, -0.0315149, -0.0115454, -0.0122457, 
-6.72242e-05, 0.00370599, -0.0164126, -0.0107853, -0.0271741, 
-0.0212005, -0.0445118, -0.0387773, -0.025109, -0.0321735, -0.0398603, 
-0.0266408, -0.0260984, -0.0296337, -0.0185381, -0.0403944, 0.0197937, 
-0.0176322, -0.013238, -0.0071666, -7.27277e-05, 0.00397489, 
0.0335056, -0.00604706, -0.00926438, 0.00706601, -0.0156982, 
-0.0275085, -0.00864179, -0.0247967, -0.030564, -0.00767327, 
-0.0235161, 0.00649758, -0.0329062, -0.0016138, -0.00701695, 
0.00819454, 0.0100377, 0.0250199, -0.0493141, -0.0216641, -0.0244709, 
-0.00466616, 0.016751, -0.0191688, -0.00492488, -0.0162364, -0.0167085, 
-0.0113427, 0.000422333, 0.030274, 0.0317995, 0.00237194, -0.00693838, 
-0.0100835), C2 = c(0.000865365, -0.001752, 0.0189917, -0.023343, 
-0.0340531, -0.0258976, -0.00794043, 0.0173163, 0.00639341, -0.0343077, 
0.01083, -0.0402179, 0.0158751, -0.00262893, -0.0216757, -0.00261259, 
-0.00542089, -0.00515714, 0.0105216, -0.0193606, 0.00692795, 
-0.0117295, -0.0235627, -0.00850041, -0.0156109, -0.00871875, 
-0.0163218, 0.0227143, -0.0161961, -0.0176719, -0.0070994, 0.0262932, 
0.00164033, -0.00969917, -0.0197631, -0.0154387, -0.0194608, 
0.00442207, -0.0234804, 0.00822342, -0.00657274, -0.0092332, 
0.0130892, -0.0345162, -0.0114187, -0.0129497, -0.00306092, 0.0417858, 
0.0262002, -0.0188849, -0.0184154, -0.0109956, -0.0151195, -0.00414531, 
0.010064, 0.0308816, -0.0153337, 0.0157867, -0.0289866, -0.0106713, 
0.000112714, -0.00152177, 0.0184509, 0.0112357, 0.00097954, 0.032083, 
0.0190258, -0.0371498, -0.0307498, -0.00947645, -0.00198995, 
0.015845, -0.0240248, -0.0122369, -0.00107049, -0.0144661, 0.0207883, 
-0.0418619, -0.0123712, -0.0212721, -0.00667244, -0.028512, -0.00522357, 
-0.018842, -0.0123026, -0.00511655, 0.0188473, 0.00739189, 0.0321578, 
-0.015449, 0.0214631, -0.00995001, -0.00144645, 0.00934907, 0.0344757, 
-0.0220224, 0.0121403, -0.00615057, -0.0208969, 0.0313899, -0.0251011, 
0.011635, 0.00536455, 0.0233033, -0.0019204, 0.0273593, 0.00844028, 
0.00181444, 0.02824, 0.0255231, 0.00266055, -0.00850383, -0.0129938, 
0.0268634, 0.0195986, 0.0320615, -0.0026514, 0.0127147, 0.014279, 
0.0553434, -0.020963, 0.00629119, -0.0244099, -0.0080923, 0.0173508, 
0.0485753, -0.00666049, 0.0501603, 0.0029162, 0.0267363, 0.0066606, 
0.00857736, 0.0172693, -0.00827586, -0.0117478, -0.00336638, 
0.00954265, -0.00889617, 0.00290055, 0.0229832, 0.0504569, 0.025979, 
-0.00795356, -0.0135421, -0.00359528, 0.0150037, -0.0105817, 
0.0167827, 0.0110882, 0.00200862, -0.00597284, -0.0188371, -0.00827599
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -153L))
```

`ann` dataframe

```
> dput(c(ann$Database_ID, ann$Profile))
c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13", "AC14", "AC15", "AC17", "AC18", 
"AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21", "AC22", "AC23", "AC24", "AC25", 
"AC26", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2", "AC30", "AC31", "AC32", "AC33", 
"AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC37", "AC38", "AC39", "AC3", "AC40", 
"AC41", "AC42", "AC43", "AC45", "AC46", "AC47", "AC48", "AC49", 
"AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53", "AC54", "AC55", "AC56", "AC57", 
"AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61", "AC62", "AC63", "AC64", "AC65", 
"AC66", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6", "AC70", "AC71", "AC72", "AC73", 
"AC74", "AC75", "AC76", "AC77", "AC78", "AC79", "AC7", "AC80", 
"AC81", "AC82", "AC83", "AC84", "AC86", "AC87", "AC88", "AC89", 
"AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC92", "AC9", "AC100", "AC101", "AC102", 
"AC103", "AC104", "AC105", "AC16", "AC68", "AC93", "AC94", "AC95", 
"AC96", "AC97", "AC99", "DE10", "DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", 
"DE16", "DE17", "DE18", "DE19", "DE1", "DE20", "DE21", "DE22", 
"DE23", "DE25", "DE26", "DE27", "DE2", "DE33", "DE34", "DE35", 
"DE36", "DE37", "DE38", "DE39", "DE3", "DE40", "DE41", "DE42", 
"DE44", "DE45", "DE46", "DE47", "DE48", "DE49", "DE4", "DE50", 
"DE51", "DE52", "DE53", "DE54", "DE55", "DE56", "DE57", "DE58", 
"DE59", "DE60", "DE7", "DE9", "DE29", "DE30", "DE32", "DE43", 
"DE5", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP", 
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", 
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", 
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.", 
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", 
"Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP", 
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", 
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.", 
"Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "BP", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Dep.", 
"BP", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.")
```

Comment: I think the issue might be that you have `||` rather than a single `|`.

Comment: (1) See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/3358272 for `&&`/`&` and `||`/`|`. (2) Note that in R-4.2, misuse of these may start throwing errors instead of just warnings; that is, `||` with length over 1 will soon error, and `if (.. | ..)` with length not equal to 1 will error instead of warn. Big changes.