# How to use R ifelse function with && function?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have the following dataset. I want to create a column that checks for rows where only A has a positive number but the rest are 0s (ifelse assignment 1 or 0). Attached is the code below. I expect the columns to have all 0s except a "1" in the last row. Currently, I am getting a "0" for the rows. Any suggestions?

```
set.seed(111)
A <- rnorm(10,10,2)
B <- c(23,0,0,0,1,2,0,1,2,0)
C <- c(1,1,23,0,0,0,1,2,0,0)
D <- c(0,1,1,23,0,0,0,1,2,0)


df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)


df$A.only <- ifelse(df$A > 0 && df$B == 0 && df$C == 0 && df$D == 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential duplicate: [Boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and)

If you use "&" instead of "&&" your command works as expected, e.g.

```r
set.seed(111)
A <- rnorm(10,10,2)
B <- c(23,0,0,0,1,2,0,1,2,0)
C <- c(1,1,23,0,0,0,1,2,0,0)
D <- c(0,1,1,23,0,0,0,1,2,0)


df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
df$A.only <- ifelse(df$A > 0 & df$B == 0 & df$C == 0 & df$D == 0, 1, 0)

df
#>            A  B  C  D A.only
#> 1  10.470441 23  1  0      0
#> 2   9.338528  0  1  1      0
#> 3   9.376752  0 23  1      0
#> 4   5.395309  0  0 23      0
#> 5   9.658248  1  0  0      0
#> 6  10.280556  2  0  0      0
#> 7   7.005147  0  1  0      0
#> 8   7.979623  1  2  1      0
#> 9   8.103049  2  0  2      0
#> 10  9.012076  0  0  0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>