# R: Operations on data.table by group, removing outliers

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in which I want to detect the presence of outliers (according to skewness and kurtosis) and, if found, correct them.

To this purpose, when an outlier is detected and `var` is the highest value, I want to set the highest value in `var` to be equal to the second highest. Below is a minimal (almost) working example of my code:

```
`%>%` <- fastpipe::`%>>%`

country <- rep(c("AA", "BB", "CC", "ZZ"), times = 4)
year <- rep(c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), each = 4)
var <- c(NA, rnorm(8, 2, 4), NA, NA, 1, 25, 19, 2, 3)

melted_data <- data.table(country, year, var)

melted_data %>%
  .[, skew := e1071::skewness(var, na.rm = TRUE), by=year] %>%
  .[, kurt:= moments::kurtosis(var, na.rm = TRUE), by=year] %>%
  .[, outliers := kurt>1 || kurt>3.5 & abs(skew)>2, by=year] %>%

  # Ranks
  .[, rank_high_first := as.integer(frank(-var, na.last="keep", ties.method="min")), by=year] %>%
  .[, rank_low_first := as.integer(frank(var, na.last="keep", ties.method="min")), by=year]  %>%

  # Identify and correct outliers
  .[rank_high_first==1, highest1 := var, by=year] %>%
  .[rank_high_first==2, highest2 := var, by=year] %>%
  .[rank_low_first==1, lowest1 := var, by=year] %>%
  .[rank_low_first==2, lowest2 := var, by=year] %>%
  .[outliers==TRUE & skew>0 & var==highest1, var<-highest2, by=year]
```

What I am trying to achieve is all in the last row. However, this does not work because the values `highest1` and `highest2` do not span the whole `year` group (edit: see also screenshot below). I think the solution would be to modify the following lines

```
.[rank_high_first==1, highest1 := var, by=year] %>%
.[rank_high_first==2, highest2 := var, by=year] %>%
```

so that `highest1` and `highest2` are copied to all rows in that year. How can I achieve that? I also tried the following, which did not work:

```
.[, highest1 := var[rank_high_first==1], by=year]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `outliers := kurt>1 || kurt>3.5...` should likely be `outliers := kurt>1 | kurt>3.5...`, which will produce very different results.

Comment: @r2evans why? Does `||` not stand for OR?

Comment: `||` is length one only. `|` is vectorized. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/3358272.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the identify and correct outliers section, I believe you can make the following change:

```
f <- function(v,r,i) v[r==i & !is.na(r)]
melted_data[, `:=`(
  highest1 = f(var,rank_high_first,1),highest2=f(var,rank_high_first,2),
  lowest1 = f(var,rank_low_first,1),lowest2=f(var,rank_low_first,2)
),by=year]
```

Also, I was wondering about your initial definition of `outliers`. Should the parentheses be added as below?:

```
  .[, outliers := kurt>1 | (kurt>3.5 & abs(skew)>2), by=year]
```

The problem you are seeing in the last two lines, I believe can be solved by:

```
  .[outliers==TRUE & skew>0 & var==highest1, var:=highest2] %>%
  .[outliers==TRUE & skew<0 & var==lowest1, var:=lowest2]
```

Note: You do not need `by=year` here, and you should use `:=` instead of `<-`

Comment: thanks! But I don't exactly understand the syntax in your first two rows. if `r` is `var`, `i` should be the highest value of `var` or... ?

Comment: oh and yes, there should be parentheses as you indicated (and the first part should be kurt>10, but just for the sake of having "outliers" in this little example..)

Comment: @gicanzo, sorry if my function, `f()` is a bit opaque. The `max` is probably a bit misleading.  `v` is `var`, `r` is the ranking column, and `i` is the value of ranking column (say 1, or 2).  When creating `highest1`, I'm sending var, rank_high_first, and 1 to the function.   The function can be re-written/improved like this: `f <- function(v,r,i) v[r==i & !is.na(r)]`, although it is the same result.  Both approaches remove any NAs, and return a single value.

Comment: I've updated the function, `f()` for improved clarity

Comment: Finally, I'm not sure why you are using `<-` in the final line.  I've offered an alternative approach which should solve your issue