# What is the Most Rly Way for Lazy Conditional Evaluation

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

The case. I have a part of code like this: `if (exists("mybooleanvar") & mybooleanvar) {statement1} else {statement2}`. I expect that if the conditions are lazily (short-circuit) evaluated a`statement1` will be run if `mybooleanvar` is not assigned and `statement2` will be called if `mybooleanvar` does not exist or equals `FALSE`.
But in practice I am getting a runtime error showing that the value of `mybooleanvar` is acessed and compared to `TRUE` if `exists("mybooleanvar") == FALSE`. So the complete boolean evaluation takes place.

Of course the issue can be solved by enclosed if statements with outer ones evaluating `exists()` and inner ones - booleans. But I wonder what is the most Rly way to properly avoid evaluation of n'th members of conditional statement if the result becomes known despite the values of further statements.
For example `statement1 & statement2` will be `FALSE` if `statement1 == FALSE`. `statement1 | statement2` is `TRUE` if `statement1 == TRUE` and `statement2` needs not to be checked (or at least this check can be switched off by something like compiler directive `{$B-)` in Delphi).

Comment: `if(exists("mybooleanvar") && mybooleanvar)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I would use `&&` instead of `&`. They differ in two ways (cf. `?"&&"`):

> The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons ...

**and:**

> The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

**Example:**

```r
foo <- function()
  if (exists("x") && (x)) cat("is TRUE\n") else cat("not existing or FALSE\n")

x <- TRUE
foo()

x <- FALSE
foo()

rm(x)
foo()
```

More can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559049/3677576) post.