# How to specify the operator in my function

Tags: r, function

Here is my dataset

```
mydata<-data.frame(
  id=1:20,
  sex=sample(c(rep("M",6),rep("F",14))),
  Age=round(rnorm(20, 30,2)),
  Weight=round(rnorm(20, 65,5),2)
)
```

I want my function to allow me to specify on which variable I want to do the filtering but also the criterion, i.e. `the operator (== or > or <=...)` and the `value (M or 65...)`

This is the function I am trying to create. I know in advance that it won't work, it's to give an idea of what I want to create.

If I don't put the variable, value and operator of selection my function must return the original database otherwise the filtered database

```
    my_func<-function(select_var, select_crit){
      
      mydata<-mydata<-if(is.null(select_var)&is.null(select_crit)){mydata}else{
        mydata[ which(mydata[select_var]select_crit), ]
      }
return(mydata)
    }
```

For example I want to be able to select all the male with my function like this

```
my_func(select_var="sex",select_crit="M"),
```

And all the induvidual > 30 (in age) like this:

`my_func(select_var="Age",select_crit=">30")`

or to select with the operator `%in%`

`my_func(select_var="Age",select_crit=%in%c(30:40))`

Comment: outside a function it should be `mydata[ which(mydata["age"]%in%c(30:40)), ]` but I've just realised that even outside the function it doesn't work. The goal is to select a range of age

Comment: I think it would be far simpler if you used three arguments: `function(sel_var, sel_fun, sel_val)`, where one could eventually do something like `do.call(sel_fun, list(mydata[[sel_var]], sel_val))`. FYI, `mydata[select_var]` should really be `mydata[[select_var]]` in your code.

Comment: Seems to me that you are hardcoding the data inside the function and this is not quite right. You should consider passing it as a variable. and if you do so `subset` function will be your friend. You do not need to write another function to do exactly what subset does

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `data` argument inside your function and apply a combination of `eval`, `parse` and `paste0` for building your filter (row selection) criterion. This approach will help:

```
my_func <- function(data, select_var=NULL, select_crit=NULL){
  
  if(is.null(select_var) & is.null(select_crit)){
    output <- data
  } else {
    output <- data[eval(parse(text=paste0("data", "$",select_var, select_crit))), select_var, drop=FALSE]
  }
  
  return(output)
}
```

Examples:

```
> my_func(mydata, select_var="Age", select_crit=">30")
   Age
1   32
5   32
7   33
8   31
9   33
13  31
16  33
18  32
19  32
> my_func(mydata, select_var="Age",select_crit="%in%c(30:40)")
   Age
1   32
2   30
5   32
7   33
8   31
9   33
11  30
13  31
14  30
16  33
17  30
18  32
19  32
```

Calling `my_func(data)` with `select_var` and `select_crit` with defult `NULL` will return your original dataset.

Comment: Why write a function like this yet there is `subset` ie `subset(mydata, Age > 30)` for example works great. Dont you think?

Comment: @onyambu, I thought the same ... I think that question should be for the OP.

Comment: Your point is well taken. But filtering the database is just one part of a longer process that needs to be done in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Three suggestions:

1. Make the data an argument of the function and not accessed via scope-breach. This helped with reproducibility, troubleshooting, maintenance, etc, and as a side-effect will allow your function to operate in `%>%`- and `|>`-pipes (if so desired).
2. Use `&&`, "never" use single-`&` in `if`-conditionals unless it is wrapped in an aggregating function such as `any` or `all`. The differences between `&` and `&&` are more than just vectorized-vs-nonvectorized, see [Boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/3358272). Further, I think you mean to use "OR" here instead of "AND", since if either one of them is null then you should not be attempting to use the operator.
3. Change from 2-args to 3-args, separating the operator from the second operand.

Try this:

```r
fun <- function(mydata, sel_var, sel_op, sel_val = NULL) {
  if (is.null(sel_var) || is.null(sel_op)) return(mydata)
  if (is.character(sel_op)) sel_op <- match.fun(sel_op)
  mydata[do.call(sel_op, c(list(mydata[[sel_var]]), if (!is.null(sel_val)) list(sel_val))),]
}

fun(mtcars, "cyl", "<", 5)
fun(mtcars, "cyl", "%in%", c(4, 8))
fun(mtcars, "vs", "!")
```

Notes:

- `sel_op` can be a function or a string representing one. This gives a lot more flexibility, such as the ability to do

  ```r
  fun(mtcars, "vs", Negate("!"))
  fun(mtcars, "vs", function(z) !!z)
  ```
- the `c(list(..), list(if (!is.null(sel_val)) ...))` is meant to allow `sel_val` to be empty/`NULL` for unary functions.