# (a>b)||(a<b) - or logical operator - what does it do?

Tags: r, operator-keyword, logical-operators, logical-or

I'm struggling to understand what the following command is checking.

```
(a>b)||(a<b)
```

I have defined a as 8 and b as 3. The returning result is TRUE.

Is this checking whether

- a>b is true; or
- a and a on both sides of the operators are equal; or
- or something else?

I tried switching around a and b in various commands to follow a pattern, but I didn't find sensible conclusion.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: it's checking if a is less than b, or b is less than a - in other words, if they're not equal to each other. You might find this helpful: https://bookdown.org/rwnahhas/IntroToR/logical.html

Comment: This is just a long way of testing whether `a` does not equal `b`. Typically this would be written as `a != b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Boolean operators && and & and between || and | in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/difference-between-boolean-operators-and-and-between-and-in-r)

Comment: Thanks! What's the impact of the double or sign (||)? Appreciate for vectors it would mean only evaluating the first element of each vector

Comment: A good example is provided in the accepted answer to the above link - if the first satisfies the condition, it returns `TRUE` regardless of anything else, if not, it moves on to the next - the author of the accepted answer in the above link provides the example that (without defining `a` at all) the expression `TRUE || a` will return `TRUE` and `TRUE | a` will return "Error: object 'a' not found". You can extend this to `FALSE || TRUE || a` which returns `TRUE` as the next evaluation after the `FALSE`  is `TRUE`