# & performance difference (lazy evaluation) from R 4.2.0 to R 4.3.1

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, logical-and

This code below benchmarks the & operation given opposite conditions that benefit or not from lazy evaluation conditions in the vectors.

```
set.seed(1)

N <- 1e6
V <- runif(N)
v1 <- V > 0.1
v2 <- V > 0.4
v3 <- V > 0.9

mb_res_le <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  times = 100, unit = "ms",
  v1 & v2 & v3, v3 & v2 & v1
)

ggplot2::autoplot(mb_res_le)
```

[image]

I understand the result from R 4.2.0. i.e. Having more `FALSE`es to the LHS of `&` performs quicker because of lazy evaluation. But I don't get how it is the other way aound for R 4.3.1 with the same comparison.

There are a few versions between 4.2.0 and 4.3.1, and this could be introduced somewhere in between, but I can't find anything in the release notes that could explain this.

I was surprised by the result from R 4.3.1. Which is why I tried earlier versions of R for which I remember being able to interpret the performance differences.

[updated plots after adding `set.seed(1)`]

Comment: [I didn't get the same results on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3QUw.png) for R version 4.3.1 - they are more consistent with your R v4.2.0 results

Comment: `Having more FALSEes to the LHS of & performs quicker because of lazy evaluation.` Does `&` do lazy evaluation, also know as short circuiting? [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/difference-between-boolean-operators-and-and-between-and-in-r) says that `&&` short circuits but `&` does not.

Comment: Taking into account NickODell's comment about falses on the LHS, and jpsmith's different performance ... if you want to do side-by-side comparisons, you need to use the same data for all tests. I suggest you add `set.seed(...)` to your question here so that we can do the same comparison on our computer using the same sequence of numbers. Otherwise, it is plausible that the number of falses on the left could be different-enough with different random seeds.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and I've updated the plots using `set.seed(1)`

It makes sense that `&` can't do short-circuiting / lazy evaluation as `&&`, because you do need to unpack the RHS. But I'd thought that the element-wise comparison still relies on `&&` which would have provided some performance benefits.

And I guess the other question, maybe more interesting, is that why the change in performance between versions?

Comment: @B.Gao I think you're overestimating how much time is needed to do the comparisons vs the actual overhead of unpacking and then compiling the results. If you are interested in that, I would suggest a more extreme example, something like `vt = rep(TRUE, n); vf = rep(FALSE, n)` and comparing `vt & vt & vt & vt & ... & vf` to `vf & vt & vt & ... & vt`, with say 20 or 30 replicates of `vt` in each expression. Using random vectors and only 3 of them really just makes any performance gains due to short circuiting less clear.

Comment: I'd also recommend enforcing the same x-scale on your plots.

Comment: For what it's worth, I took my own advice and did a comparison with `vf & {20 vt}` vs `{20 vt} & vf`. I bumped up to `times = 1000`. The distributions look identical, just slightly shifted with the "`vf` first" version being about 4.4 milliseconds faster. I'm on R 4.2.2.

Comment: ... and, I don't have a 4.3.* installation on my machine, but I ran the same code on a free-tier Posit Cloud install of 4.3.1. With different machines, I can't tell you which R version is faster, but I can verify that the distributions look identical - there is no apparent performance flip between the two expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Docker allows us to compare easily. I happen to have R 4.3.1 (current) and R 4.2.3 (final of the previous release cycle) here.  I simply added `install.packages("microbenchmark")` and printed the result summary.

Then for R 4.3.1:

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
 v1 & v2 & v3  8.815923  9.328674 10.49479  9.990183 11.14268 16.22374   100
 v3 & v2 & v1 10.906409 11.338012 12.42658 12.030553 12.90834 18.53381   100
```

and for R 4.2.3

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 v1 & v2 & v3  8.869552  9.362924 10.41865  9.83979 11.12159 14.79225   100
 v3 & v2 & v1 10.700630 11.142198 12.26546 11.61229 13.11973 17.68791   100
```

and modulo normal variation during benchmarking seem identical.

#### Modified code

```
set.seed(1)

N <- 1e6
V <- runif(N)
v1 <- V > 0.1
v2 <- V > 0.4
v3 <- V > 0.9

install.packages("microbenchmark")

mb_res_le <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 100, unit = "ms", 
                                            v1 & v2 & v3, v3 & v2 & v1)
print(mb_res_le)

#ggplot2::autoplot(mb_res_le)
```

#### Call

This is the one for 4.2.3, and 4.3.1 is obviously similar:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v $PWD:/mnt -w /mnt rocker/r-base:4.2.3 Rscript question.R
```