# How to slove 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)' in paleofire package

Tags: r, if-statement

I am using **paleofire** package v1.2.4 under R version 4.3
0, which is available from https://github.com/oblarquez/paleofire. Although the package hasn't been updated for a while, I want to use its inner function to do data transformation via **pfTransform** function.

The following code comes from its original package paper
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300414001861

```
library(paleofire)
ID<-pfSiteSel(id_site%in% id_site&num_samp>=20)
TR_1=pfTransform(ID, method=c("MinMax","Box-Cox","Z-Score"),BasePeriod = c(0,12000))
```

and it throws an error

```
Error in method == "RunMean" || method == "RunMin" : 
  'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

I searched that the problem may results from "||", so I replected "||" by "|" and run the **pfTransform** function itself from authors https://github.com/oblarquez/paleofire/blob/master/R/pfTransform.R

and generates a new error

```
Error in if (method == "RunMean" | method == "RunMin" | method == "RunMed" |  : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

I tried to contact the maintainer but haven't got reply.I was wondering if there is way to slove the problem and let the function run.

Many thanks

Comment: Already tried `if (method %in% c("RunMean", "RunMin", "RunMed", "RunMax", "RunQuantile"))`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Just tried the code and gave the same error `Error in if (method %in% c("RunMean", "RunMin", "RunMed", "RunMax", "RunQuantile")) { : 
  the condition has length > 1`

Comment: `if (any(method %in% c("RunMean", "RunMin", "RunMed", "RunMax", "RunQuantile")))` shoud work

Comment: Tried this.  And comes our with `Error in if (method != "NULL") { : the condition has length > 1`

Comment: Try `if (!is.null(method) && method %in% c("RunMean", "RunMin", "RunMed", "RunMax", "RunQuantile"))`.

Comment: I think you're mis-using `pfTransform`. All of the error messages you're showing suggest that the author expects `method` to be length 1, so any error you get is most likely not a bug in the function but instead a bug in how you are using it. I suggest (to the package author, if they're around) that a check be added, e.g., `stopifnot(length(method) == 1L)`. If you (Yuwan) are trying to update the function so that you can run multiple methods simultaneously (idk if that makes sense) then everywhere `method` is used you must change the logic.

Comment: FYI, `if (method == "RunMean" | method == "RunMin" | ...)` is wrong, either use `method %in% c(..)` or use `||`. "Never" use `|` or `&` in an `if` conditional unless the logic is wrapped in a summarizing function like `any` or `all` (others exist). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/3358272

Comment: Thanks, jay.sf. But it gets back to the original warning message `Error in !is.null(method) && method %in% c("RunMean", "RunMin", "RunMed",  : 
  'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'`

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. I got the same feeling that I need to define the logic, but I am not good at coding, so don't have any idea to improve the if statement. The original code uses "||", but it doesn't work well for some reason (the last update about this function is several years ago), I tried to use method %in% c(..) to update the function which is previously suggested by jay.sf, but it is not working as well. Thanks for pointing me to the misuse of "|".

Comment: `||` does not work well because it was (I'm inferring) never intended that the length of `method` is anything other than 1. If you really read the source for that function, see that it is intended to do ONE METHOD per call; namely, the internal variables eventually used to return something all are calculated differently based on which (_one_) `method` you provide. The more I look at the function, the error is in what you are trying to do with it, not with the function itself. (Having said that ... any function that calls `install.packages(.)` on me will be promptly uninstalled, that is _BAD_)