# R Statement Counting Number of Rows with Double Criterion Now Fails in Later R Version

Tags: r

I just upgraded from a 3.x version of R to R 4.3.2.
Now this statement is throwing an error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
intCountTheNumberOfBackgroundCPUPctRows = 
  nrow(MyData[(MyData$column == "background-cpu-pct" &&
         MyData$OracleDatabaseEntity == myvar)])
# Error: Error in MyData$column == "background-cpu-pct" && MyData$OracleDatabaseEntity == :
#   'length = 710' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

I am counting rows for a double criterion.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: This is a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/3358272 (difference between `&` and `&&`) and the fact that recent R versions has made it an error to use `&&` with vectors over length-1. I suspect you need `&` instead, assuming sight-unseen that `MyData` is of class `"data.frame"` with more than one row of data.

Comment: BTW, I suggest it might be safer in the long run to be explicit that your logical is in the `i=` component of `[`-indexing, likely `intCountTheNumberOfBackgroundCPUPctRows = nrow(MyData[(MyData$column == "background-cpu-pct" & MyData$OracleDatabaseEntity == myvar),])`. Frankly, we don't need to return a frame from the logical, we can do just `intCountTheNumberOfBackgroundCPUPctRows = sum(with(MyData, column == "background-cpu-pct" & OracleDatabaseEntity == myvar))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely due to `MyData$column == "background-cpu-pct" && MyData$OracleDatabaseEntity == myvar`. Since [R 4.2.0](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.2.0/NEWS.R-4.2.0.html):

> Calling `&&` or `||` with either argument of length greater than one now gives a warning (which it is intended will become an error).

It looks like that's exactly what you're doing. Now, this should just generate a warning. I suspect if you run `getOption("warn")` the output will be `2` or greater, meaning warnings are converted to errors. I can replicate your error if I do that:

```r
options(warn = 2)
c(TRUE, FALSE) && c(TRUE, TRUE)
# Error in c(TRUE, FALSE) && c(TRUE, TRUE) : 
#   (converted from warning) 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

You could convert this back to a warning by setting `options(warn = 0)`. However, you probably just want to do:

```r
c(TRUE, FALSE) & c(TRUE, TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Or in your case, `MyData$column == "background-cpu-pct" & MyData$OracleDatabaseEntity == myvar`